# Efficiently merging two data frames on a non-trivial criteria

Tags: r, merge, data.table

Answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821862/data-selection-error/18823432#18823432) last night, I spent a good hour trying to find a solution that didn't grow a `data.frame` in a for loop, without any success, so I'm curious if there's a better way to go about this problem.

The general case of the problem boils down to this:

- Merge two `data.frames`
- Entries in either `data.frame` can have 0 or more matching entries in the other.
- We only care about entries that have 1 or more matches across both.
- The match function is complex involving multiple columns in both `data.frame`s

For a concrete example I will use similar data to the linked question:

```
genes <- data.frame(gene       = letters[1:5], 
                    chromosome = c(2,1,2,1,3),
                    start      = c(100, 100, 500, 350, 321),
                    end        = c(200, 200, 600, 400, 567))
markers <- data.frame(marker = 1:10,
                   chromosome = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 1, 2),
                   position   = c(105, 300, 96, 206, 150, 400, 25, 300, 120, 700))
```

And our complex matching function:

```
# matching criteria, applies to a single entry from each data.frame
isMatch <- function(marker, gene) {
  return(
    marker$chromosome == gene$chromosome & 
    marker$postion >= (gene$start - 10) &
    marker$postion <= (gene$end + 10)
  )
}
```

The output should look like an `sql` `INNER JOIN` of the two data.frames, for entries where `isMatch` is `TRUE`.
I've tried to construct the two `data.frames` so that there can be 0 or more matches in the other `data.frame`.

The solution I came up with is as follows:

```
joined <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:nrow(genes)) {
   # This repeated subsetting returns the same results as `isMatch` applied across
   # the `markers` data.frame for each entry in `genes`.
   matches <- markers[which(markers$chromosome == genes[i, "chromosome"]),]
   matches <- matches[which(matches$pos >= (genes[i, "start"] - 10)),]
   matches <- matches[which(matches$pos <= (genes[i, "end"] + 10)),]
   # matches may now be 0 or more rows, which we want to repeat the gene for:
   if(nrow(matches) != 0) {
     joined <- rbind(joined, cbind(genes[i,], matches[,c("marker", "position")]))
   }
}
```

Giving the results:

```
   gene chromosome start end marker position
1     a          2   100 200      3       96
2     a          2   100 200      4      206
3     b          1   100 200      1      105
4     b          1   100 200      5      150
5     b          1   100 200      9      120
51    e          3   321 567      6      400
```

This is quite an ugly and clungy solution, but anything else I tried was met with failure:

- use of `apply`, gave me a `list` where each element was a matrix,
  with no way to `rbind` them.
- I can't specify the dimensions of `joined` first, because I don't
  know how many rows I will need in the end.

I'm sure I will come up with a problem of this general form in the future. So what's the correct way to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: When i run your code I get output (`joined`) that doesn't really make sense, can you show what you're expecting for the output from your demo?

Comment: Whoops! There was a bug (`>=` should have been `<=` in one instance).
Fixed and updated with the output I get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A data table solution: a rolling join to fulfill the first inequality, followed by a vector scan to satisfy the second inequality. The join-on-first-inequality will have more rows than the final result (and therefore may run into memory issues), but it will be smaller than a straight-up merge in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18840716/).

```
require(data.table)

genes_start <- as.data.table(genes)
## create the start bound as a separate column to join to
genes_start[,`:=`(start_bound = start - 10)]
setkey(genes_start, chromosome, start_bound)

markers <- as.data.table(markers)
setkey(markers, chromosome, position)

new <- genes_start[
    ##join genes to markers
    markers, 
    ##rolling the last key column of genes_start (start_bound) forward
    ##to match the last key column of markers (position)
    roll = Inf, 
    ##inner join
    nomatch = 0
##rolling join leaves positions column from markers
##with the column name from genes_start (start_bound)
##now vector scan to fulfill the other criterion
][start_bound <= end + 10]
##change names and column order to match desired result in question
setnames(new,"start_bound","position")
setcolorder(new,c("chromosome","gene","start","end","marker","position"))
   # chromosome gene start end marker position
# 1:          1    b   100 200      1      105
# 2:          1    b   100 200      9      120
# 3:          1    b   100 200      5      150
# 4:          2    a   100 200      3       96
# 5:          2    a   100 200      4      206
# 6:          3    e   321 567      6      400
```

One could do a double join, but as it involves re-keying the data table before the second join, I don't think that it will be faster than the vector scan solution above.

```
##makes a copy of the genes object and keys it by end
genes_end <- as.data.table(genes)
genes_end[,`:=`(end_bound = end + 10, start = NULL, end = NULL)]
setkey(genes_end, chromosome, gene, end_bound)

## as before, wrapped in a similar join (but rolling backwards this time)
new_2 <- genes_end[
    setkey(
        genes_start[
        markers, 
        roll = Inf, 
        nomatch = 0
    ], chromosome, gene, start_bound), 
    roll = -Inf, 
    nomatch = 0
]
setnames(new2, "end_bound", "position")
```

Comment: You absolutely win this. What took 29 minutes with `sqldf` on my full dataset takes just under 2 seconds with `data.table`! 

And you're right about the second code block -- it's almost twice as slow at just under 4 seconds.

Comment: Are the end results identical? I only checked on the test dataset, so I don't know whether it is good for your full dataset.

Comment: I didn't check exactly, but the number of rows came out roughly the same, so I assume so.

Comment: Although I may get a speed increase in `sqldf` if I create similar `start_bound` and `end_bound` columns.

Comment: +1 I haven't fully followed but can't `roll` be set to `-10` and `+10` directly?

Comment: @MatthewDowle I attempted that initially, but had some trouble. I believe `roll = -10` sets the match so that `start - 10 <= position <= start`, instead of the desired `start - 10 <= position`.

Answer (score 4):

I dealt with a very similar problem myself by doing the merge, and sorting out which rows satisfy the condition afterwards. I don't claim that this is a universal solution, if you're dealing with large datasets where there will be few entries that match the condition, this will likely be inefficient. But to adapt it to your data:

```
joined.raw <- merge(genes, markers)
joined <- joined.raw[joined.raw$position >= (joined.raw$start -10) & joined.raw$position <= (joined.raw$end + 10),]
joined
#    chromosome gene start end marker position
# 1           1    b   100 200      1      105
# 2           1    b   100 200      5      150
# 4           1    b   100 200      9      120
# 10          2    a   100 200      4      206
# 11          2    a   100 200      3       96
# 16          3    e   321 567      6      400
```

Comment: Much more elegant! But you're right, creating the whole merged `data.frame` is probably not ideal.

Comment: Yes, I agree - this is only convenient depending on the data

Answer (score 2):

Another answer I've come up with using the `sqldf` package.

```
sqldf("SELECT gene, genes.chromosome, start, end, marker, position 
       FROM genes JOIN markers ON genes.chromosome = markers.chromosome 
       WHERE position >= (start - 10) AND position <= (end + 10)")
```

Using `microbenchmark` it performs comparably to @alexwhan's `merge` and `[` method.

```
> microbenchmark(alexwhan, sql)
Unit: nanoseconds
     expr min    lq median  uq  max neval
 alexwhan 435 462.5  468.0 485 2398   100
      sql 422 456.5  466.5 498 1262   100
```

I've also attempted to test both functions on some real data of the same format I have lying around (35,000 rows for `genes`, 2,000,000 rows for `markers`, with the `joined` output coming to 480,000 rows).

Unfortunately `merge` seems unable to handle this much data, falling over at `joined.raw <- merge(genes, markers)` with an error (which i don't get if reduce the number of rows):

```
Error in merge.data.frame(genes, markers) : 
  negative length vectors are not allowed
```

While the `sqldf` method runs successfully in 29 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

After almost one year regarding to this problem you solved for me... now i spent some time to deal with this using another way by awk....

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$0;next}{for (i in a){split(a[i],x," ");if (x[2]==$2 && x[3]-10 <=$3 && x[4]+10 >=$3)print x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4],$0}}' gene.txt makers.txt > genesnp.txt
```

which produce the kind of same results:

```
b   1   100 200 1   1   105
a   2   100 200 3   2   96
a   2   100 200 4   2   206
b   1   100 200 5   1   150
e   3   321 567 6   3   400
b   1   100 200 9   1   120
```