# Join two datasets based on an inequality condition

Tags: r, join, merge, dataset, sqldf

I have used the call below to "join" my datasets based on an inequality condition:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select *
from dataset1 a,
dataset2 b
a.col1 <= b.col2")
```

However, is there a way I can do this without **sqldf**?

So far, I can only see merge functions that are based on simple joins on a particular common column.

Thanks!

Comment: check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840410/efficiently-merging-two-data-frames-on-a-non-trivial-criteria the answer applies i believe.

Comment: The word `on` is missing before `a.col1`.

Answer (score 5):

Non-equi (or conditional) joins were recently implemented in data.table, and available in the current development version, v1.9.7. See installation instructions [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.7+
setDT(dataset1) # convert to data.tables
setDT(dataset2)
dataset1[dataset2, on=.(col1 < col2), nomatch=0L]
```

For each row of `dataset2`, find matching row indices while joining on condition provided to the `on` argument, and return all columns for those matching rows.

Answer (score 1):

I've had that problem a few times and I think I got a solution using `dplyr`! It might not be the best in terms of efficiency, but it works. I'll suppose you have a constant variable in each case called 'dummy' (or alternatively, it can be another variable to join by). Moreover, I assume dataset1's columns are a_colj and those of dataset2 are b_colj:

```
dataset1 %>%
    inner_join(dataset2, by='dummy') %>%
    filter(a_col1 <= b_col2)
```

Answer (score 1):

In `dplyr`, you can use `join_by` for inequality joins. Use `closest` to get only the closest match:

```r
sales <- tibble(
  id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L),
  sale_date = as.Date(c("2018-12-31", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-05", "2019-01-04", "2019-01-01"))
)
sales
#      id sale_date 
# 1     1 2018-12-31
# 2     1 2019-01-02
# 3     1 2019-01-05
# 4     2 2019-01-04
# 5     2 2019-01-01

promos <- tibble(
  id = c(1L, 1L, 2L),
  promo_date = as.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-05", "2019-01-02"))
)
#      id promo_date
# 1     1 2019-01-01
# 2     1 2019-01-05
# 3     2 2019-01-02

left_join(sales, promos, join_by(id, sale_date >= promo_date))
#      id sale_date  promo_date
# 1     1 2018-12-31 NA        
# 2     1 2019-01-02 2019-01-01
# 3     1 2019-01-05 2019-01-01
# 4     1 2019-01-05 2019-01-05
# 5     2 2019-01-04 2019-01-02
# 6     2 2019-01-01 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely do it in two steps utilizing `merge`.

Example (the exact details of the merge are up to you):

```
lessRows <- which(df1$col1 < df2$col2)
df3 <- merge(df1, df2)[lessRows, ]
```