# Filter a Dataframe by Another Dataframe

Tags: r

Supposedly this question has already been answered. But the user who flagged my question failed to test the solution and the cited question does not work for my problem.

I have found questions on how to filter a dataframe using another list but I have not found something that shows how to filter a dataframe using another dataframe.

I have two dataframes and the first one can be thought of as a key of ID's and dates.

```
   id       date
1 id1 2016-06-23
2 id2 2016-06-25
3 id3 2016-06-23
4 id4 2016-06-25
5 id5 2016-06-27

structure(list(id = structure(1:5, .Label = c("id1", "id2", "id3", 
"id4", "id5"), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(16975, 16977, 
16975, 16977, 16979), class = "Date")), .Names = c("id", "date"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I then have a second dataframe with ID's and dates and I would like to filter the second dataframe to only return rows that are *after* the date for the ID in the first row.

Here is the second dataframe:

```
   id       date
1 id1 2016-06-20
2 id1 2016-06-23
3 id1 2016-06-24
4 id2 2016-06-23
5 id3 2016-06-27

structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("id1", 
"id2", "id3"), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(16972, 16975, 
16976, 16975, 16979), class = "Date")), .Names = c("id", "date"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

And this is what the results would look like:

```
   id       date
1 id1 2016-06-24
2 id3 2016-06-27
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Join two datasets based on an inequality condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893022/join-two-datasets-based-on-an-inequality-condition)

Comment: Did you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38464306/2573061)?  "I'll suppose you have a constant variable in each case called 'dummy' (or alternatively, it can be another variable to join by)" -- in your case the "alternatively"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution using `data.table`:**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d1)
setDT(d2)
merge(d1, d2, "id")[date.y > date.x, .(id, date = date.y)]

    id       date
1: id1 2016-06-24
2: id3 2016-06-27
```

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 can you give a link?

Comment: There is an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38464382/2573061) that is conditional only (no equi-join on id).  See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46433040/2573061) for example w/ both.  I still think this question is a dupe though.

Answer (score 3):

Thank god there is `dplyr`. The following code joins `df1` which has unique identifiers, and keeps only these rows (`filter`) which matches condition `date >= date.1`.

Be careful, because by default when you have identical column names in both data.frames, dplyr will join by all of them. Then we have to specify `by` parameter and add suffix to variables names to differ identical column names.

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

df2 %>%
 left_join(df1, by = "id", suffix=c("",".2") ) %>%
 filter( date > date.2) %>%
 select( -date.2 )

#  id       date
# 1 id1 2016-06-23
# 2 id1 2016-06-24
# 3 id3 2016-06-27
```

Comment: This result differs from OPs expected output

Comment: replace `>=` with `>` because OP specifies "after" not "on or after"

Answer (score 3):

### Use non-equi-join in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

setnames(df1, 'date','date1') # disambiguate for conditional join

df1[df2, on=.(id, date1<date), nomatch=0]
```

Returns:

```
  id      date1
1: id1 2016-06-24
2: id3 2016-06-27
```

On large datasets I expect this approach to be faster than any approach which uses `dplyr` and/or a cartesian join followed by a filter.

Comment: Why the downvote?  This is probably the most efficient solution offered...

Answer (score 0):

So your first dataframe is basically an index. Assuming that index is called df1, and your second dataframe that you want to filter is df2, I would do this using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

df.result <- left_join(df2, df1, by = "id") %>% 
   filter(date.x > date.y) %>% 
   select(-date.y)
```

eta: this would be the result:

```
   id     date.x
 1 id1 2016-06-24
 2 id3 2016-06-27
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of Gonzo's answer

Comment: Well I didn't see that before I posted mine, but it's not an exact duplicate. Mine is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

[`join_by`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join_by.html) was added in dplyr 1.1.0 for more advanced join specifications:

```
library(dplyr)

inner_join(df2, df1, by = join_by(id == id, date > date)) |>
  select(id, date = date.x)
```

Note the equality condition and inequality conditions both have the same variable names. They are distinguished by the order of the data frames. The LHS refers to the first data frame (`df2` in this case) and the RHS to the second data frame (`df1` in this case).