# How to join a data.frame of keys and datetimes with a window of values from a time series?

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series

I'd like to be able to join a dataframe...

1. `concerts` that has:

   - a column of keys (`venue`)
   - a column of date-times (`start_time`)

     - The `start_time`s represent the time at which the concert began at the venue.

...with a number of other dataframes that are effectively time series. For example, the dataframe...

2. `temperatures` has:

   - a column of keys (also `venue`)
   - a column of hourly date-times (`datetime`) that span the entire time frame (many days before the concert times and many days after).
   - a `temperature` column

What I want to have in the joined result is: the temperature at the venue at the start hour of the concert, but also at the end of the first, second, third, and fourth hours of the concert. Essentially a 4-hour 'window' of temperatures.

The only approach I can think of is to create lagged columns in `temperatures` (one for each of the 1st-4th hours of the concert), and then to join with `concerts` on the venue and start hours. But this is very slow when applied to my actual dataset, which has many more columns than just temperature.

Here is the example data I've cooked up.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

concerts <- tibble(venue = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
                    start_time = ymd_hm(c("2019-08-09 08:05",
                                     "2019-08-10 16:07",
                                     "2019-08-09 09:30",
                                     "2019-08-10 17:15"))
                   )

temperatures <- tibble(venue = c(rep("A", 50),
                                   rep("B", 50)),
                datetime = rep(seq(ymd_hm("2019-08-09 00:00"), by = "hour", length.out = 50), 2),
                temperature = c(rnorm(50, 60, 5),
                         rnorm(50, 95, 5))
                )
```

Here is my successful but expensive attempt, with the desired results in `temperature_over_course_of_concerts`.

```
temperatures_lagged <- temperatures  %>%
  mutate(temperature_1hr_in = lag(temperature, 1),
         temperature_2hr_in = lag(temperature, 2),
         temperature_3hr_in = lag(temperature, 3),
         temperature_4hr_in = lag(temperature, 4)) %>%
  rename(temperature_start = temperature)

temperature_over_course_of_concerts <- concerts %>%
  mutate(start_hour = floor_date(start_time, unit = "hour")) %>%
  left_join(temperatures_lagged, by = c("venue" = "venue", "start_hour" = "datetime"))
```

Comment: Would look into non-equi joins, which let you join on a window: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893022/join-two-datasets-based-on-an-inequality-condition