# Finding row index in lookup table with inexact matches and vectorized code in r

Tags: r, conditional-statements, vectorization

I am essentially trying to join two sets of data. However, the data has inexact matches (e.g., a date in the main data that is between a start and stop date in the lookup table). I know that fuzzy_join works, but I cannot use it due to memory space, which has forced me to use for loops. The data set continues to grow (> 3,000,000 rows) and for loops are now taking multiple days to run, so I am trying to find a faster way to index the rows in the lookup table.

The following is a very simplified version of what I am currently doing. Sorry that the data is a bit non-sensical (it was what I could quickly come up with for a fake data set).

I would be most happy with a way to use the multi-contitional which statment without useing a loop--even if it just outputs the row number(s) of the lookup table that match the row of interest in the main data set.

```
df<-cars# main data

#Creating matching data for a lookup table
lookup<-cars[-which(duplicated(cars)),]
lookup$location<-state.abb[-1]

#linking the main data to the lookup table analogous to a left_join
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  row <- which(lookup[,"speed"] == df[i,"speed"] &
                 lookup[,"dist"]==df[i,"dist"])
  if (length(row)==1){df[i,"location"]<-lookup[row,"location"]}
  else if (length(row)!=1){df[i,"location"]<-"Error"}
}
```

The following is an example where the data more closely matches the question as per another users request.

```
Lookup<-structure(list(Deploy = structure(c(18575, 18575, 18575, 18575, 
18575, 18464, 18573, 18573, 18573), class = "Date"), Retrieved = structure(c(18978, 
18978, 18978, 18978, 18978, 18978, 18978, 18978, 18978), class = "Date"), 
    Station = c("484451", "484449", "484450", "484452", "484453", 
    "483231", "484457", "484456", "484455"), Name = c("A", "B", 
    "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I")), row.names = c(7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 16L, 27L, 33L, 34L), class = "data.frame")

df<-structure(list(DateTime = c("2020-11-07 14:48:17 CST", "2021-04-24 12:31:50 CDT", 
"2021-04-28 00:03:56 CDT", "2021-04-30 21:53:25 CDT", "2021-05-08 08:22:37 CDT", 
"2021-05-14 13:01:15 CDT", "2021-05-20 02:29:43 CDT", "2021-05-24 13:54:15 CDT", 
"2021-05-30 04:11:33 CDT", "2021-06-03 03:38:52 CDT", "2021-06-06 01:40:47 CDT", 
"2021-06-09 04:05:07 CDT", "2021-06-13 22:55:06 CDT", "2021-06-18 15:19:01 CDT", 
"2021-06-30 01:12:33 CDT", "2021-08-13 19:04:24 CDT", "2021-09-07 19:41:25 CDT", 
"2021-11-19 19:36:32 CST", "2021-12-02 19:37:50 CST", "2021-03-31 07:50:39 CDT", 
"2021-04-16 02:25:56 CDT", "2021-04-26 23:12:17 CDT", "2021-05-03 15:00:23 CDT", 
"2021-05-12 05:50:45 CDT", "2021-05-18 15:00:19 CDT", "2021-05-28 22:52:07 CDT", 
"2021-06-05 15:29:18 CDT", "2021-06-12 11:18:47 CDT", "2021-06-19 04:10:22 CDT", 
"2021-06-30 10:11:13 CDT", "2021-08-14 08:21:32 CDT", "2021-06-28 15:54:43 CDT", 
"2021-07-04 12:44:51 CDT", "2021-02-14 22:28:41 CST", "2021-03-14 15:14:28 CDT", 
"2021-04-16 05:10:42 CDT", "2021-04-20 00:52:10 CDT", "2021-04-23 06:11:06 CDT", 
"2021-04-26 16:45:59 CDT", "2021-04-30 03:43:53 CDT", "2021-05-03 11:11:58 CDT", 
"2021-05-07 15:27:46 CDT", "2021-05-11 05:51:15 CDT", "2021-05-14 06:06:39 CDT", 
"2021-05-17 07:08:14 CDT", "2021-05-20 08:26:21 CDT", "2021-05-23 16:48:55 CDT", 
"2021-05-27 23:53:04 CDT", "2021-05-31 17:05:24 CDT", "2021-06-03 21:19:24 CDT", 
"2021-06-07 00:20:27 CDT", "2021-06-10 16:06:36 CDT", "2021-06-13 20:26:05 CDT", 
"2021-06-17 04:28:53 CDT", "2021-06-20 15:26:44 CDT", "2021-06-24 05:24:39 CDT", 
"2021-06-28 13:57:09 CDT", "2021-07-02 12:13:23 CDT", "2021-07-05 23:31:31 CDT", 
"2021-07-09 06:34:07 CDT", "2021-07-13 17:30:26 CDT", "2021-07-17 19:38:44 CDT", 
"2021-07-21 17:24:29 CDT", "2021-07-26 19:54:42 CDT", "2021-07-31 15:53:39 CDT", 
"2021-08-05 05:57:23 CDT", "2021-08-09 14:34:04 CDT", "2021-08-13 20:34:30 CDT", 
"2021-08-17 21:23:28 CDT", "2021-08-21 04:37:26 CDT", "2021-08-24 03:23:49 CDT", 
"2021-08-28 11:22:34 CDT", "2021-08-31 23:20:26 CDT", "2021-09-08 03:54:07 CDT", 
"2021-09-11 23:29:38 CDT", "2021-09-16 00:53:41 CDT", "2021-09-25 02:26:09 CDT", 
"2021-09-29 22:28:42 CDT", "2021-10-05 03:27:17 CDT", "2021-10-08 23:44:34 CDT", 
"2021-10-12 11:56:38 CDT", "2021-10-20 02:28:34 CDT", "2021-11-05 19:02:55 CDT", 
"2021-03-09 05:58:50 CST", "2021-04-13 16:46:42 CDT", "2021-04-18 14:34:43 CDT", 
"2021-04-25 08:38:19 CDT", "2021-05-06 00:53:20 CDT", "2021-05-12 16:45:31 CDT", 
"2021-05-21 23:56:06 CDT", "2021-06-05 20:38:45 CDT", "2021-06-16 14:57:06 CDT", 
"2021-07-05 14:54:37 CDT", "2021-07-25 23:25:06 CDT", "2021-08-15 11:22:27 CDT", 
"2021-08-31 21:25:10 CDT", "2021-10-03 18:53:57 CDT", "2021-11-08 16:03:34 CST", 
"2021-02-16 01:15:13 CST", "2021-03-06 00:28:03 CST"), Station = c("483231", 
"484449", "484449", "484449", "484449", "484449", "484449", "484449", 
"484449", "484449", "484449", "484449", "484449", "484449", "484449", 
"484449", "484449", "484449", "484449", "484450", "484450", "484450", 
"484450", "484450", "484450", "484450", "484450", "484450", "484450", 
"484450", "484450", "484451", "484453", "484455", "484455", "484455", 
"484455", "484455", "484455", "484455", "484455", "484455", "484455", 
"484455", "484455", "484455", "484455", "484455", "484455", "484455", 
"484455", "484455", "484455", "484455", "484455", "484455", "484455", 
"484455", "484455", "484455", "484455", "484455", "484455", "484455", 
"484455", "484455", "484455", "484455", "484455", "484455", "484455", 
"484455", "484455", "484455", "484455", "484455", "484455", "484455", 
"484455", "484455", "484455", "484455", "484455", "484456", "484456", 
"484456", "484456", "484456", "484456", "484456", "484456", "484456", 
"484456", "484456", "484456", "484456", "484456", "484456", "484457", 
"484457"), ID = c("26382", "52448", "52448", "52448", "59597", 
"52481", "59685", "59597", "59625", "52448", "59607", "59597", 
"52476", "52452", "52443", "52490", "52452", "59607", "52484", 
"52478", "52459", "52476", "52452", "52456", "52448", "52476", 
"52490", "52461", "52452", "59597", "52488", "52481", "52465", 
"52430", "52434", "52553", "52545", "52433", "52497", "52439", 
"52535", "59617", "59620", "59686", "52553", "54225", "54225", 
"50313", "50313", "52549", "52549", "59620", "28726", "52436", 
"56724", "59683", "52436", "50315", "59683", "59684", "52555", 
"52431", "28723", "59683", "52431", "52431", "52497", "52559", 
"52497", "52541", "52523", "59684", "52436", "59683", "59684", 
"59684", "52431", "59617", "52436", "52436", "52555", "52436", 
"59684", "52497", "59617", "52522", "52497", "52549", "52535", 
"59686", "52496", "52436", "59617", "52497", "59682", "52436", 
"59683", "59685", "52430", "52438")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(15682L, 
113503L, 123508L, 133522L, 143529L, 153531L, 163546L, 173553L, 
183563L, 193570L, 203578L, 213582L, 223586L, 233588L, 243592L, 
253608L, 263609L, 279539L, 291018L, 308142L, 320585L, 332244L, 
343277L, 354611L, 365588L, 377103L, 388219L, 399208L, 410181L, 
421791L, 438325L, 490101L, 570616L, 581633L, 595778L, 610533L, 
621113L, 631630L, 642195L, 652737L, 663238L, 674401L, 685098L, 
695576L, 706043L, 716540L, 727054L, 737734L, 748313L, 758811L, 
769297L, 779851L, 790361L, 800892L, 811420L, 821980L, 832634L, 
843246L, 853770L, 864265L, 874930L, 885540L, 896129L, 906876L, 
917594L, 928287L, 938949L, 949584L, 960180L, 970680L, 981116L, 
991790L, 1002945L, 1014113L, 1025331L, 1036973L, 1049346L, 1060826L, 
1072594L, 1084158L, 1095904L, 1108937L, 1123610L, 1142055L, 1157723L, 
1168503L, 1179545L, 1191392L, 1202620L, 1214257L, 1226959L, 1238952L, 
1252276L, 1265805L, 1279392L, 1292293L, 1308823L, 1328560L, 1342239L, 
1354986L))

for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  Row<-which(Lookup[,"Station"]==df[i,"Station"] & 
               Lookup[,"Deploy"]<=df[i,"DateTime"] &
               Lookup[,"Retrieved"]>=df[i,"DateTime"])
  if (length(Row)==1){df[i,"Location"]<-Lookup[Row,"Name"]}
  else if (length(Row)!=1){df[i,"Location"]<-"Error"}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect task for the `data.table` package, which is known to be fast and memory efficient. Consider the following implementation.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(Lookup)
setDT(df)
tz <- function(x) as.POSIXct(x, "America/Chicago")
cols <- c("Deploy", "Retrieved")

df[, DateTime := tz(DateTime)]
Lookup[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, \(x) tz(format(x))), .SDcols = cols]

df[Lookup, Location := Name, on = .(
  Station, DateTime <= Retrieved, DateTime >= Deploy
)][, Location := fifelse(is.na(Location), "Error", Location)]
```

Note that almost everything here is done by reference so no extra copy is created. This should work as long as you can fully load `df` into the memory.

Output

```
                DateTime Station    ID Location
  1: 2020-11-07 14:48:17  483231 26382        F
  2: 2021-04-24 12:31:50  484449 52448        B
  3: 2021-04-28 00:03:56  484449 52448        B
  4: 2021-04-30 21:53:25  484449 52448        B
  5: 2021-05-08 08:22:37  484449 59597        B
  6: 2021-05-14 13:01:15  484449 52481        B
  7: 2021-05-20 02:29:43  484449 59685        B
  8: 2021-05-24 13:54:15  484449 59597        B
  9: 2021-05-30 04:11:33  484449 59625        B
 10: 2021-06-03 03:38:52  484449 52448        B
 11: 2021-06-06 01:40:47  484449 59607        B
 12: 2021-06-09 04:05:07  484449 59597        B
 13: 2021-06-13 22:55:06  484449 52476        B
 14: 2021-06-18 15:19:01  484449 52452        B
 15: 2021-06-30 01:12:33  484449 52443        B
 16: 2021-08-13 19:04:24  484449 52490        B
 17: 2021-09-07 19:41:25  484449 52452        B
 18: 2021-11-19 19:36:32  484449 59607        B
 19: 2021-12-02 19:37:50  484449 52484        B
 20: 2021-03-31 07:50:39  484450 52478        C
 21: 2021-04-16 02:25:56  484450 52459        C
 22: 2021-04-26 23:12:17  484450 52476        C
 23: 2021-05-03 15:00:23  484450 52452        C
 24: 2021-05-12 05:50:45  484450 52456        C
 25: 2021-05-18 15:00:19  484450 52448        C
 26: 2021-05-28 22:52:07  484450 52476        C
 27: 2021-06-05 15:29:18  484450 52490        C
 28: 2021-06-12 11:18:47  484450 52461        C
 29: 2021-06-19 04:10:22  484450 52452        C
 30: 2021-06-30 10:11:13  484450 59597        C
 31: 2021-08-14 08:21:32  484450 52488        C
 32: 2021-06-28 15:54:43  484451 52481        A
 33: 2021-07-04 12:44:51  484453 52465        E
 34: 2021-02-14 22:28:41  484455 52430        I
 35: 2021-03-14 15:14:28  484455 52434        I
 36: 2021-04-16 05:10:42  484455 52553        I
 37: 2021-04-20 00:52:10  484455 52545        I
 38: 2021-04-23 06:11:06  484455 52433        I
 39: 2021-04-26 16:45:59  484455 52497        I
 40: 2021-04-30 03:43:53  484455 52439        I
 41: 2021-05-03 11:11:58  484455 52535        I
 42: 2021-05-07 15:27:46  484455 59617        I
 43: 2021-05-11 05:51:15  484455 59620        I
 44: 2021-05-14 06:06:39  484455 59686        I
 45: 2021-05-17 07:08:14  484455 52553        I
 46: 2021-05-20 08:26:21  484455 54225        I
 47: 2021-05-23 16:48:55  484455 54225        I
 48: 2021-05-27 23:53:04  484455 50313        I
 49: 2021-05-31 17:05:24  484455 50313        I
 50: 2021-06-03 21:19:24  484455 52549        I
 51: 2021-06-07 00:20:27  484455 52549        I
 52: 2021-06-10 16:06:36  484455 59620        I
 53: 2021-06-13 20:26:05  484455 28726        I
 54: 2021-06-17 04:28:53  484455 52436        I
 55: 2021-06-20 15:26:44  484455 56724        I
 56: 2021-06-24 05:24:39  484455 59683        I
 57: 2021-06-28 13:57:09  484455 52436        I
 58: 2021-07-02 12:13:23  484455 50315        I
 59: 2021-07-05 23:31:31  484455 59683        I
 60: 2021-07-09 06:34:07  484455 59684        I
 61: 2021-07-13 17:30:26  484455 52555        I
 62: 2021-07-17 19:38:44  484455 52431        I
 63: 2021-07-21 17:24:29  484455 28723        I
 64: 2021-07-26 19:54:42  484455 59683        I
 65: 2021-07-31 15:53:39  484455 52431        I
 66: 2021-08-05 05:57:23  484455 52431        I
 67: 2021-08-09 14:34:04  484455 52497        I
 68: 2021-08-13 20:34:30  484455 52559        I
 69: 2021-08-17 21:23:28  484455 52497        I
 70: 2021-08-21 04:37:26  484455 52541        I
 71: 2021-08-24 03:23:49  484455 52523        I
 72: 2021-08-28 11:22:34  484455 59684        I
 73: 2021-08-31 23:20:26  484455 52436        I
 74: 2021-09-08 03:54:07  484455 59683        I
 75: 2021-09-11 23:29:38  484455 59684        I
 76: 2021-09-16 00:53:41  484455 59684        I
 77: 2021-09-25 02:26:09  484455 52431        I
 78: 2021-09-29 22:28:42  484455 59617        I
 79: 2021-10-05 03:27:17  484455 52436        I
 80: 2021-10-08 23:44:34  484455 52436        I
 81: 2021-10-12 11:56:38  484455 52555        I
 82: 2021-10-20 02:28:34  484455 52436        I
 83: 2021-11-05 19:02:55  484455 59684        I
 84: 2021-03-09 05:58:50  484456 52497        H
 85: 2021-04-13 16:46:42  484456 59617        H
 86: 2021-04-18 14:34:43  484456 52522        H
 87: 2021-04-25 08:38:19  484456 52497        H
 88: 2021-05-06 00:53:20  484456 52549        H
 89: 2021-05-12 16:45:31  484456 52535        H
 90: 2021-05-21 23:56:06  484456 59686        H
 91: 2021-06-05 20:38:45  484456 52496        H
 92: 2021-06-16 14:57:06  484456 52436        H
 93: 2021-07-05 14:54:37  484456 59617        H
 94: 2021-07-25 23:25:06  484456 52497        H
 95: 2021-08-15 11:22:27  484456 59682        H
 96: 2021-08-31 21:25:10  484456 52436        H
 97: 2021-10-03 18:53:57  484456 59683        H
 98: 2021-11-08 16:03:34  484456 59685        H
 99: 2021-02-16 01:15:13  484457 52430        G
100: 2021-03-06 00:28:03  484457 52438        G
                DateTime Station    ID Location
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use an [inequality join](https://learnsql.com/blog/illustrated-guide-sql-non-equi-join/) with the [sqldf](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=sqldf) package.  See [Join two datasets based on an inequality condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893022/join-two-datasets-based-on-an-inequality-condition). The important part is the four lines involved in the inner join.

If you're really comparing datetimes (in df) against dates (in Lookup), things can simplify because you can cast/keep everything as dates.

This code assumes:

1. All the timezones are equivalent.
2. The station number has to match.
3. The `DateTime` value must be bounded by `Deploy` and `Retrieved`.

```r
df <-
  df |> 
  dplyr::mutate(
    Date = as.Date(DateTime),
  )

sql <- 
  "
    SELECT
      df.ID
      ,df.Station
      ,df.Date
      ,Lookup.Deploy
      ,Lookup.Retrieved
      ,Lookup.Name
    FROM df
      inner join Lookup on 
        df.Station = Lookup.Station
        and
        df.Date between Lookup.Deploy and Lookup.Retrieved
  "

sqldf::sqldf(sql) |> 
  tibble::as_tibble()
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 100 x 6
   ID    Station Date       Deploy     Retrieved  Name 
   <chr> <chr>   <date>     <date>     <date>     <chr>
 1 26382 483231  2020-11-07 2020-07-21 2021-12-17 F    
 2 52448 484449  2021-04-24 2020-11-09 2021-12-17 B    
 3 52448 484449  2021-04-28 2020-11-09 2021-12-17 B    
 4 52448 484449  2021-04-30 2020-11-09 2021-12-17 B    
 5 59597 484449  2021-05-08 2020-11-09 2021-12-17 B    
 6 52481 484449  2021-05-14 2020-11-09 2021-12-17 B    
 7 59685 484449  2021-05-20 2020-11-09 2021-12-17 B    
 8 59597 484449  2021-05-24 2020-11-09 2021-12-17 B    
 9 59625 484449  2021-05-30 2020-11-09 2021-12-17 B    
10 52448 484449  2021-06-03 2020-11-09 2021-12-17 B    
# ... with 90 more rows
```

---

*Alternate Version*:
If for some reason you need to compare dates against datetimes (*e.g.*, the timezones aren't equivalent), there's a little extra work to align the data types.

```r
df <-
  df |> 
  dplyr::mutate(
    DateTime = as.POSIXct(DateTime),
  )

Lookup <-
  Lookup |>
  dplyr::mutate(
    DeployDT    = as.POSIXct(paste0(Deploy    , "00:00:00")),
    RetrievedDT = as.POSIXct(paste0(Retrieved , "00:00:00")),
  )

sql <- 
  "
    SELECT
      df.ID
      ,df.Station
      ,df.DateTime
      ,Lookup.DeployDT
      ,Lookup.RetrievedDT
      ,Lookup.Name
    FROM df
      inner join Lookup on 
        df.Station = Lookup.Station
        and
        df.DateTime between Lookup.DeployDT and Lookup.RetrievedDT
        
        -- equivalent to
        -- (Lookup.DeployDT <= df.DateTime) and (df.DateTime <= Lookup.RetrievedDT)
  "

sqldf::sqldf(sql) |> 
  tibble::as_tibble() |> 
  dplyr::mutate(
    Deploy    = as.Date(DeployDT),
    Retrieved = as.Date(RetrievedDT),
  ) |> 
  dplyr::select(
    -DeployDT,
    -RetrievedDT,
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for the response `@wibeasley`. I have added data that more closely matches the real data.

Comment: Great, that makes this whole page more relevant to others.  My answer uses your new data.

Comment: Suggest not overwriting Lookup and df variables as that makes it hard to run it twice.  The second time the original input has been lost and it must be regenerated.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, good point. Do you like this version? It doesn't overwrite variables.  It also focuses on the simpler, more likely, scenario.

Comment: It still uses df <- df ... and Lookup <- Lookup <- ...

Comment: Oh, I gotcha.  I guess that's my style --to clean up variables in existing datasets instead of creating duplicate datasets where I might accidentally use the wrong one.  Assuming the source is always available to be queried again.  I'd rather cast that Date/DateTime variable to its correct data type.  And for `DeployDT` & `RetrievedDT`, the two variables are easily dropped.