# dplyr left_join by less than, greater than condition

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join, r-faq

This question is somewhat related to issues [Efficiently merging two data frames on a non-trivial criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840410/efficiently-merging-two-data-frames-on-a-non-trivial-criteria) and [Checking if date is between two dates in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353595/checking-if-date-is-between-two-dates-in-r). And the one I have posted here requesting if the feature exist:
[GitHub issue](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/557)

I am looking to join two dataframes using `dplyr::left_join()`. The condition I use to join is less-than, greater-than i.e, `<=` and `>`. Does `dplyr::left_join()` support this feature? or do the keys only take `=` operator between them. This is straightforward to run from SQL (assuming I have the dataframe in the database)

Here is a MWE: I have two datasets one firm-year (`fdata`), while second is sort of survey data that happens once every five years. So for all years in the `fdata` that are in between two survey years, I join the corresponding survey year data.

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,
        2,2,2,2,2,2,
        3,3,3,3,3,3,
        5,5,5,5,
        8,8,8,8,
        13,13,13)

fyear <- c(1998,1999,2000,2001,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,
       1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,1998,1999,2000,2001,
       1998,1999,2000,2001,1998,1999,2000)

byear <- c(1990,1995,2000,2005)
eyear <- c(1995,2000,2005,2010)
val <- c(3,1,5,6)

sdata <- tbl_df(data.frame(byear, eyear, val))

fdata <- tbl_df(data.frame(id, fyear))

test1 <- left_join(fdata, sdata, by = c("fyear" >= "byear","fyear" < "eyear"))
```

I get

> ```
> Error: cannot join on columns 'TRUE' x 'TRUE': index out of bounds
> ```

Unless if `left_join` can handle the condition, but my syntax is missing something?

Comment: You may wish to subscribe to https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2240

Comment: I'm happy to see the new version of dplyr will support non-equi joins, see new answer below for example of the syntax, very similar to what you originally wanted: `left_join(fdata, sdata, join_by(fyear >= byear,fyear < eyear))`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The original answer below is out of date, as pointed out in another answer. With newer versions of `dplyr`, simply use the following. (Note that this syntax works even with database backends using `dbplyr`.)

```r
fdata %>% 
left_join(sdata,
          join_by(fyear >= byear, fyear < eyear))
```

---

When the original answer was created, there was no easy way to do inequality joins using `dplyr`.

**Original answer**

Use a `filter`. (But note that this answer does *not* produce a correct `LEFT JOIN`; but the MWE gives the right result with an `INNER JOIN` instead.)

The `dplyr` package isn't happy if asked merge two tables without something to merge on, so in the following, I make a dummy variable in both tables for this purpose, then filter, then drop `dummy`:

```
fdata %>% 
    mutate(dummy=TRUE) %>%
    left_join(sdata %>% mutate(dummy=TRUE)) %>%
    filter(fyear >= byear, fyear < eyear) %>%
    select(-dummy)
```

And note that if you do this in PostgreSQL (for example), the query optimizer sees through the `dummy` variable as evidenced by the following two query explanations:

```
> fdata %>% 
+     mutate(dummy=TRUE) %>%
+     left_join(sdata %>% mutate(dummy=TRUE)) %>%
+     filter(fyear >= byear, fyear < eyear) %>%
+     select(-dummy) %>%
+     explain()
Joining by: "dummy"
<SQL>
SELECT "id" AS "id", "fyear" AS "fyear", "byear" AS "byear", "eyear" AS "eyear", "val" AS "val"
FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT "id", "fyear", TRUE AS "dummy"
FROM "fdata") AS "zzz136"

LEFT JOIN 

(SELECT "byear", "eyear", "val", TRUE AS "dummy"
FROM "sdata") AS "zzz137"

USING ("dummy")) AS "zzz138"
WHERE "fyear" >= "byear" AND "fyear" < "eyear"


<PLAN>
Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..50886.88 rows=322722 width=40)
  Join Filter: ((fdata.fyear >= sdata.byear) AND (fdata.fyear < sdata.eyear))
  ->  Seq Scan on fdata  (cost=0.00..28.50 rows=1850 width=16)
  ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..33.55 rows=1570 width=24)
        ->  Seq Scan on sdata  (cost=0.00..25.70 rows=1570 width=24)
```

and doing it more cleanly with SQL gives *exactly* the same result:

```
> tbl(pg, sql("
+     SELECT *
+     FROM fdata 
+     LEFT JOIN sdata 
+     ON fyear >= byear AND fyear < eyear")) %>%
+     explain()
<SQL>
SELECT "id", "fyear", "byear", "eyear", "val"
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM fdata 
    LEFT JOIN sdata 
    ON fyear >= byear AND fyear < eyear) AS "zzz140"


<PLAN>
Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..50886.88 rows=322722 width=40)
  Join Filter: ((fdata.fyear >= sdata.byear) AND (fdata.fyear < sdata.eyear))
  ->  Seq Scan on fdata  (cost=0.00..28.50 rows=1850 width=16)
  ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..33.55 rows=1570 width=24)
        ->  Seq Scan on sdata  (cost=0.00..25.70 rows=1570 width=24)
```

Comment: As noted, this does not produce a proper left_join because it drops rows from the left dataset without matches within the filter on the right.

Answer (score 30):

`data.table` adds non-equi joins starting from v 1.9.8

```
library(data.table) #v>=1.9.8
setDT(sdata); setDT(fdata) # converting to data.table in place

fdata[sdata, on = .(fyear >= byear, fyear < eyear), nomatch = 0,
      .(id, x.fyear, byear, eyear, val)]
#    id x.fyear byear eyear val
# 1:  1    1998  1995  2000   1
# 2:  2    1998  1995  2000   1
# 3:  3    1998  1995  2000   1
# 4:  5    1998  1995  2000   1
# 5:  8    1998  1995  2000   1
# 6: 13    1998  1995  2000   1
# 7:  1    1999  1995  2000   1
# 8:  2    1999  1995  2000   1
# 9:  3    1999  1995  2000   1
#10:  5    1999  1995  2000   1
#11:  8    1999  1995  2000   1
#12: 13    1999  1995  2000   1
#13:  1    2000  2000  2005   5
#14:  2    2000  2000  2005   5
#15:  3    2000  2000  2005   5
#16:  5    2000  2000  2005   5
#17:  8    2000  2000  2005   5
#18: 13    2000  2000  2005   5
#19:  1    2001  2000  2005   5
#20:  2    2001  2000  2005   5
#21:  3    2001  2000  2005   5
#22:  5    2001  2000  2005   5
#23:  8    2001  2000  2005   5
#24:  2    2002  2000  2005   5
#25:  3    2002  2000  2005   5
#26:  2    2003  2000  2005   5
#27:  3    2003  2000  2005   5
#    id x.fyear byear eyear val
```

You can also get this to work with `foverlaps` in 1.9.6 with a little more effort.

Comment: `setDF` can be used afterwards if somebody wants to returns his datasets to plain data.frame

Comment: @eddi
After the join, in fetching columns is there a data.table equivalent of .(i.*, x.fear)
i.e. all columns from table i but only fear from table x
Thank you.

Comment: This solution is cleaner and faster than the `tidyr`/`dplyr` one, and works when adding more conditions.

Comment: The fyear >= byear, fyear < eyear looks great and appears to imply and AND operator.  My code is not correctly selecting the records within each period.  I've searched the docs, have seen a reference to a mysterious vignette about join and rolling join that I can't find.  Could you point me to the right place to understand conditional element of the join?

Comment: Turns out I need to add the equivalent of .(fyear = x. fyear,.... after the on element, otherwise fyear seems to get replaced by byear (as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41043047/complexe-non-equi-merge-in-r).  Not sure why but it works now.  If there was a explanation of this in a vignette, that would be great.

Answer (score 23):

This looks like it is the sort of task that package **fuzzyjoin** addresses.  The various functions of the package look and work similar to the **dplyr** join functions.

In this case one of the `fuzzy_*_join` functions will work for you.  The main difference between `dplyr::left_join` and `fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join` is that you give a list of functions to use in the matching process with the `match.fun` argument.  Note the `by` argument still is written the same as it would in `left_join`.

Below is an example.  The functions I used to match on are `>=` and `<` for the `fyear` to `byear` and the `fyear` to `eyear` comparisons, respectively.  The

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

fuzzy_left_join(fdata, sdata, 
             by = c("fyear" = "byear", "fyear" = "eyear"), 
             match_fun = list(`>=`, `<`))

Source: local data frame [27 x 5]

      id fyear byear eyear   val
   (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
1      1  1998  1995  2000     1
2      1  1999  1995  2000     1
3      1  2000  2000  2005     5
4      1  2001  2000  2005     5
5      2  1998  1995  2000     1
6      2  1999  1995  2000     1
7      2  2000  2000  2005     5
8      2  2001  2000  2005     5
9      2  2002  2000  2005     5
10     2  2003  2000  2005     5
..   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
```

Comment: This does not scale well, but is a nice and easy to understand solution

Comment: @aosmith Thanks for the solution. Would it be possible to extend the interval? i.e., `fyear >= byear-20` and `fyear < eyear+5`

Comment: This does not seem to work for dates - it chockes very fast, compared to an Excel vlookup on the same data.

Answer (score 10):

`dplyr v1.1.0` now includes the ability to do non-equi joins like this, with almost exactly the syntax you tried. For data with many partial matches, this will be much more performant than using `fuzzyjoin` or a `filter` step after an over-inclusive join.

```r
# Relies on dplyr >=1.1.0, released Jan 2023
library(dplyr)
left_join(fdata, sdata, join_by(fyear >= byear,fyear < year))
```

Comment: As of [January, 29, 2023](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2023/01/dplyr-1-1-0-joins/) this has been added to production dplyr version 1.10

Comment: Also `join_by(between(fyear, byear, eyear, bounds = "[)"))`

Answer (score 2):

One option is to join row-wise as a list column, and then unnest the column:

```
# evaluate each row individually
fdata %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    # insert list column of single row of sdata based on conditions
    mutate(s = list(sdata %>% filter(fyear >= byear, fyear < eyear))) %>% 
    # unnest list column
    tidyr::unnest()

# Source: local data frame [27 x 5]
# 
#       id fyear byear eyear   val
#    (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
# 1      1  1998  1995  2000     1
# 2      1  1999  1995  2000     1
# 3      1  2000  2000  2005     5
# 4      1  2001  2000  2005     5
# 5      2  1998  1995  2000     1
# 6      2  1999  1995  2000     1
# 7      2  2000  2000  2005     5
# 8      2  2001  2000  2005     5
# 9      2  2002  2000  2005     5
# 10     2  2003  2000  2005     5
# ..   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
```

Comment: Like my answer, this does not produce a valid `LEFT JOIN`. Augment the left data frame with observations with `fyear==2011` and then filter the result of your query on `fyear==2011` and there's nothing there. This works in SQL: `SELECT * FROM fdata LEFT JOIN sdata ON fyear >= year AND fyear < eyear`.