# Check if a date is within an interval in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I have these three intervals defined:

```
YEAR_1  <- interval(ymd('2002-09-01'), ymd('2003-08-31'))
YEAR_2  <- interval(ymd('2003-09-01'), ymd('2004-08-31')) 
YEAR_3  <- interval(ymd('2004-09-01'), ymd('2005-08-31'))
```

(in real life, I have 50 of these)

I have a dataframe (called `df`) with a column full of lubridate formatted dates.

I'd like to append a new column on `df` which has the appropriate value `YEAR_n`, depending on which interval the date falls within.

Something like:

```
df$YR <- ifelse(df$DATE %within% YEAR_1, 1, NA)
```

but I'm not sure how to proceed. I need to somehow use an `apply` I think?

Here's my dataframe:

```
structure(c(1055289600, 1092182400, 1086220800, 1074556800, 1109289600, 
1041897600, 1069200000, 1047427200, 1072656000, 1048636800, 1092873600, 
1090195200, 1051574400, 1052179200, 1130371200, 1242777600, 1140652800, 
1137974400, 1045526400, 1111104000, 1073952000, 1052870400, 1087948800, 
1053993600, 1039564800, 1141603200, 1074038400, 1105315200, 1060560000, 
1072051200, 1046217600, 1107129600, 1088553600, 1071619200, 1115596800, 
1050364800, 1147046400, 1083628800, 1056412800, 1159747200, 1087257600, 
1201478400, 1120521600, 1066176000, 1034553600, 1057622400, 1078876800, 
1010880000, 1133913600, 1098230400, 1170806400, 1037318400, 1070409600, 
1091577600, 1057708800, 1182556800, 1091059200, 1058227200, 1061337600, 
1034121600, 1067644800, 1039478400, 1022198400, 1063065600, 1096329600, 
1049760000, 1081728000, 1016150400, 1029801600, 1059350400, 1087257600, 
1181692800, 1310947200, 1125446400, 1057104000, NA, 1085529600, 
1037664000, 1091577600, 1080518400, 1110758400, 1092787200, 1094601600, 
1169424000, 1232582400, 1058918400, 1021420800, 1133136000, 1030320000, 
1060732800, 1035244800, 1090800000, 1129161600, 1055808000, 1060646400, 
1028678400, 1075852800, 1144627200, 1111363200, 1070236800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")
```

Comment: Related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41132081/find-which-interval-row-in-a-data-frame-that-each-element-of-a-vector-belongs-in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everybody has their favourite tool for this, mine happens to be [data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki) because of what it refers to as its `dt[i, j, by]` logic.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(date = as.IDate(pt))

dt[, YR := 0.0 ]                        # I am using a numeric for year here...

dt[ date >= as.IDate("2002-09-01") & date <= as.IDate("2003-08-31"), YR := 1 ]
dt[ date >= as.IDate("2003-09-01") & date <= as.IDate("2004-08-31"), YR := 2 ]
dt[ date >= as.IDate("2004-09-01") & date <= as.IDate("2005-08-31"), YR := 3 ]
```

I create a `data.table` object, converting your times to date for later comparison. I then set up a new column, defaulting to one.

We then execute three conditional statements: for each of the three intervals (which I just create by hand using the endpoints), we set the `YR` value to 1, 2 or 3.

This does have the desired effect as we can see from

```
R> print(dt, topn=5, nrows=10)
           date YR
  1: 2003-06-11  1
  2: 2004-08-11  2
  3: 2004-06-03  2
  4: 2004-01-20  2
  5: 2005-02-25  3
 ---              
 96: 2002-08-07  0
 97: 2004-02-04  2
 98: 2006-04-10  0
 99: 2005-03-21  3
100: 2003-12-01  2
R> table(dt[, YR])

 0  1  2  3 
26 31 31 12 
R>
```

One could have done this also simply by computing date differences and truncating down, but it is also nice to be a little explicit at times.

*Edit:* A more generic form just uses arithmetic on the dates:

```
R> dt[, YR2 := trunc(as.numeric(difftime(as.Date(date), 
+                                        as.Date("2001-09-01"),
+                                        unit="days"))/365.25)]
R> table(dt[, YR2])

 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  9 
 7 31 31 12  9  5  1  2  1 
R>
```

This does the job in one line.

Comment: David gives a nice version of this using non-equi-joins in data.table over here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/41132376/496803 , so long as the intervals are specified in a data.table with start/stop/year columns.

Comment: What is `pt`? Thanks

Comment: if you're going to use `data.table`, may as well use `%between%` ;-)

Comment: @MichaelChirico  Quite right.  I knew there was another operator (which I use too infrequently)  but I looked in the wrong corner.

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck In my answer `pt` is the _vector_ from your saved structure which, despite your claim, is actually _not_ a data.frame (but just a single column `POSIXct` vector). I assigned that to `pt`, and then form a data.table.

Comment: oops! You are correct. Making a MRE lead me to create a vector, whereas I should have made it a dataframe. Curious, why the letters `pt`? I understand using `df` for a dataframe; why does `pt` refer to a vector?

Comment: `pt` is just a shorthand I have been using -- it can stand for 'parsed time (object)', or short for 'POSIXt', or ...   My bad to not have my answer fully reproducible, and for not catching your comment here until today.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `walk` from package `purrr` for this:

```
purrr::walk(1:3, ~(df$Year[as.POSIXlt(df$DATE) %within% get(paste0("YEAR_", .))] <<- .))
```

or maybe you should write a loop to improve readability (unless taboo for you):

```
df$YR <- NA
for(i in 1:3){
  interval <- get(paste0("YEAR_", i))
  index <-which(as.POSIXlt(df$DATE) %within% interval)
  df$YR[index] <- i
}
```

Comment: this worked incredibly fast on a vector containing 2,2 million elements.

Answer (score 5):

With `lubridate` and `mapply`:

```
library(lubridate)

dates <- # your data here

# no idea how you generated these, so let's just copy them
YEAR_1 <- interval(ymd('2002-09-01'), ymd('2003-08-31'))
YEAR_2 <- interval(ymd('2003-09-01'), ymd('2004-08-31')) 
YEAR_3 <- interval(ymd('2004-09-01'), ymd('2005-08-31'))

# this should scale nicely
sapply(c(YEAR_1, YEAR_2, YEAR_3), function(x) { mapply(`%within%`, dates, x) })
```

The result is a matrix with one column per interval:

```
        [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
  [1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
  [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
  [3,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
  [4,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
  ... etc. (100 rows in your example data)
```

There might be a nicer way to code that with `purrr`, but I am too novice to `purrr` to see it.

Comment: I like it, but seems to run really slow and create a pretty big object

Comment: Correct, it runs OK on 10,000 rows but is far too slow above that. There must be a bottleneck somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
df = as.data.frame(structure(c(1055289600, 1092182400, 1086220800, 1074556800, 1109289600, 
            1041897600, 1069200000, 1047427200, 1072656000, 1048636800, 1092873600, 
            1090195200, 1051574400, 1052179200, 1130371200, 1242777600, 1140652800, 
            1137974400, 1045526400, 1111104000, 1073952000, 1052870400, 1087948800, 
            1053993600, 1039564800, 1141603200, 1074038400, 1105315200, 1060560000, 
            1072051200, 1046217600, 1107129600, 1088553600, 1071619200, 1115596800, 
            1050364800, 1147046400, 1083628800, 1056412800, 1159747200, 1087257600, 
            1201478400, 1120521600, 1066176000, 1034553600, 1057622400, 1078876800, 
            1010880000, 1133913600, 1098230400, 1170806400, 1037318400, 1070409600, 
            1091577600, 1057708800, 1182556800, 1091059200, 1058227200, 1061337600, 
            1034121600, 1067644800, 1039478400, 1022198400, 1063065600, 1096329600, 
            1049760000, 1081728000, 1016150400, 1029801600, 1059350400, 1087257600, 
            1181692800, 1310947200, 1125446400, 1057104000, NA, 1085529600, 
            1037664000, 1091577600, 1080518400, 1110758400, 1092787200, 1094601600, 
            1169424000, 1232582400, 1058918400, 1021420800, 1133136000, 1030320000, 
            1060732800, 1035244800, 1090800000, 1129161600, 1055808000, 1060646400, 
            1028678400, 1075852800, 1144627200, 1111363200, 1070236800), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                   "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"))

colnames(df)[1] = "dates"

YEAR_1_Start = as.Date('2002-09-01')
YEAR_1_End = as.Date('2003-08-31')

YEAR_2_Start = as.Date('2003-09-01')
YEAR_2_End = as.Date('2004-08-31')

YEAR_3_Start = as.Date('2004-09-01')
YEAR_3_End = as.Date('2005-08-31')


df$year = lapply(df$dates,FUN = function(x){
          x = as.Date(x)
          if(is.na(x)){
            return(NA)
          }else if(YEAR_1_Start <= x & x <= YEAR_1_End){
            return("YEAR_1")
          }else if(YEAR_2_Start <= x & x <= YEAR_2_End){
            return("YEAR_2")
          }else if(YEAR_3_Start <= x & x <= YEAR_3_End){
            return("YEAR_3")
          }else{
            return("Other")
          }
})

df
         dates   year
1   2003-06-11 YEAR_1
2   2004-08-11 YEAR_2
3   2004-06-03 YEAR_2
4   2004-01-20 YEAR_2
5   2005-02-25 YEAR_3
6   2003-01-07 YEAR_1
7   2003-11-19 YEAR_2
8   2003-03-12 YEAR_1
9   2003-12-29 YEAR_2
10  2003-03-26 YEAR_1
11  2004-08-19 YEAR_2
12  2004-07-19 YEAR_2
13  2003-04-29 YEAR_1
14  2003-05-06 YEAR_1
15  2005-10-27  Other
16  2009-05-20  Other
17  2006-02-23  Other
18  2006-01-23  Other
19  2003-02-18 YEAR_1
20  2005-03-18 YEAR_3
21  2004-01-13 YEAR_2
22  2003-05-14 YEAR_1
23  2004-06-23 YEAR_2
24  2003-05-27 YEAR_1
25  2002-12-11 YEAR_1
26  2006-03-06  Other
27  2004-01-14 YEAR_2
28  2005-01-10 YEAR_3
29  2003-08-11 YEAR_1
30  2003-12-22 YEAR_2
31  2003-02-26 YEAR_1
32  2005-01-31 YEAR_3
33  2004-06-30 YEAR_2
34  2003-12-17 YEAR_2
35  2005-05-09 YEAR_3
36  2003-04-15 YEAR_1
37  2006-05-08  Other
38  2004-05-04 YEAR_2
39  2003-06-24 YEAR_1
40  2006-10-02  Other
41  2004-06-15 YEAR_2
42  2008-01-28  Other
43  2005-07-05 YEAR_3
44  2003-10-15 YEAR_2
45  2002-10-14 YEAR_1
46  2003-07-08 YEAR_1
47  2004-03-10 YEAR_2
48  2002-01-13  Other
49  2005-12-07  Other
50  2004-10-20 YEAR_3
51  2007-02-07  Other
52  2002-11-15 YEAR_1
53  2003-12-03 YEAR_2
54  2004-08-04 YEAR_2
55  2003-07-09 YEAR_1
56  2007-06-23  Other
57  2004-07-29 YEAR_2
58  2003-07-15 YEAR_1
59  2003-08-20 YEAR_1
60  2002-10-09 YEAR_1
61  2003-11-01 YEAR_2
62  2002-12-10 YEAR_1
63  2002-05-24  Other
64  2003-09-09 YEAR_2
65  2004-09-28 YEAR_3
66  2003-04-08 YEAR_1
67  2004-04-12 YEAR_2
68  2002-03-15  Other
69  2002-08-20  Other
70  2003-07-28 YEAR_1
71  2004-06-15 YEAR_2
72  2007-06-13  Other
73  2011-07-18  Other
74  2005-08-31 YEAR_3
75  2003-07-02 YEAR_1
76        <NA>     NA
77  2004-05-26 YEAR_2
78  2002-11-19 YEAR_1
79  2004-08-04 YEAR_2
80  2004-03-29 YEAR_2
81  2005-03-14 YEAR_3
82  2004-08-18 YEAR_2
83  2004-09-08 YEAR_3
84  2007-01-22  Other
85  2009-01-22  Other
86  2003-07-23 YEAR_1
87  2002-05-15  Other
88  2005-11-28  Other
89  2002-08-26  Other
90  2003-08-13 YEAR_1
91  2002-10-22 YEAR_1
92  2004-07-26 YEAR_2
93  2005-10-13  Other
94  2003-06-17 YEAR_1
95  2003-08-12 YEAR_1
96  2002-08-07  Other
97  2004-02-04 YEAR_2
98  2006-04-10  Other
99  2005-03-21 YEAR_3
100 2003-12-01 YEAR_2
```

Edit:

If you can get your intervals into a data.frame or data.table we can change the lapply easily to account for this:

```
df$year = lapply(df$dates,FUN = function(x){
  x = as.Date(x)
  if(is.na(x)){
    return(NA)
  }
  for(i in 1:nrow(intervals){
    if(df.intervals[i,"Start"]<=x & x<= df.intervals[i,"End"]){
                    return(paste0(YEAR_,i))}
}})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on it all. I Like to keep things tidy ;)

```
> ## load libraries
> library(tidyverse)
> library(lubridate)
> 
> ## define times
> times <- c(1055289600, 1092182400, 1086220800, 1074556800, 1109289600, 
+            1041897600, 1069200000, 1047427200, 1072656000, 1048636800, 1092873600, 
+            1090195200, 1051574400, 1052179200, 1130371200, 1242777600, 1140652800, 
+            1137974400, 1045526400, 1111104000, 1073952000, 1052870400, 1087948800, 
+            1053993600, 1039564800, 1141603200, 1074038400, 1105315200, 1060560000, 
+            1072051200, 1046217600, 1107129600, 1088553600, 1071619200, 1115596800, 
+            1050364800, 1147046400, 1083628800, 1056412800, 1159747200, 1087257600, 
+            1201478400, 1120521600, 1066176000, 1034553600, 1057622400, 1078876800, 
+            1010880000, 1133913600, 1098230400, 1170806400, 1037318400, 1070409600, 
+            1091577600, 1057708800, 1182556800, 1091059200, 1058227200, 1061337600, 
+            1034121600, 1067644800, 1039478400, 1022198400, 1063065600, 1096329600, 
+            1049760000, 1081728000, 1016150400, 1029801600, 1059350400, 1087257600, 
+            1181692800, 1310947200, 1125446400, 1057104000, NA, 1085529600, 
+            1037664000, 1091577600, 1080518400, 1110758400, 1092787200, 1094601600, 
+            1169424000, 1232582400, 1058918400, 1021420800, 1133136000, 1030320000, 
+            1060732800, 1035244800, 1090800000, 1129161600, 1055808000, 1060646400, 
+            1028678400, 1075852800, 1144627200, 1111363200, 1070236800)
> times <- tibble(time = as.POSIXct(times, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")) %>% 
+   mutate(time = as_date(time),
+          duplicated = duplicated(time)) ## there are duplicated times!
> 
> 
> ## define years
> year <- c("YEAR_1", "YEAR_2", "YEAR_3")
> interval <- c(interval(ymd("2002-09-01", tz = "UTC"), ymd("2003-08-31", tz = "UTC")),
+               interval(ymd("2003-09-01", tz = "UTC"), ymd("2004-08-31", tz = "UTC")),
+               interval(ymd("2004-09-01", tz = "UTC"), ymd("2005-08-31", tz = "UTC")))
> years <- tibble(year, interval)
> 
> ## check data
> times
# A tibble: 100 x 2
   time       duplicated
   <date>     <lgl>     
 1 2003-06-11 FALSE     
 2 2004-08-11 FALSE     
 3 2004-06-03 FALSE     
 4 2004-01-20 FALSE     
 5 2005-02-25 FALSE     
 6 2003-01-07 FALSE     
 7 2003-11-19 FALSE     
 8 2003-03-12 FALSE     
 9 2003-12-29 FALSE     
10 2003-03-26 FALSE     
# ... with 90 more rows
> years
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  year   interval                      
  <chr>  <S4: Interval>                
1 YEAR_1 2002-09-01 UTC--2003-08-31 UTC
2 YEAR_2 2003-09-01 UTC--2004-08-31 UTC
3 YEAR_3 2004-09-01 UTC--2005-08-31 UTC
> 
> ## create new indicator variavble
> ##
> ## join datasets (length = 3 x 100)
> ## indicator for year
> ## drop NAs
> ## keep "time" and "active"
> ## join with times to get back at full dataset
> ## as duplications, keep only one of them
> crossing(times, years) %>% 
+   mutate(active = if_else(time %within% interval, year, NA_character_)) %>% 
+   drop_na(active) %>% 
+   select(time, active) %>% 
+   right_join(times, by = "time") %>% 
+   distinct() %>% 
+   select(-duplicated)
# A tibble: 100 x 2
   time       active
   <date>     <chr> 
 1 2003-06-11 YEAR_1
 2 2004-08-11 YEAR_2
 3 2004-06-03 YEAR_2
 4 2004-01-20 YEAR_2
 5 2005-02-25 YEAR_3
 6 2003-01-07 YEAR_1
 7 2003-11-19 YEAR_2
 8 2003-03-12 YEAR_1
 9 2003-12-29 YEAR_2
10 2003-03-26 YEAR_1
# ... with 90 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

### We can :

**1st:** create a `data.table` contains all `YEAR_N`

```
> interval.dt <- data.table(Interval = c(YEAR_1, YEAR_2, YEAR_3))
> interval.dt
#                         Interval
#1: 2002-09-01 UTC--2003-08-31 UTC
#2: 2003-09-01 UTC--2004-08-31 UTC
#3: 2004-09-01 UTC--2005-08-31 UTC
```

**2nd:** define a function to get row index of `interval.dt` when a specific year date fall in range `interval.dt$Interval` using `int_start(interval.dt$Interval) < year < int_end(interval.dt$Interval)`

```
>  findYearIndex <- function(year) {
      interval.dt[,which(int_start(interval.dt$Interval) < year & year < int_end(interval.dt$Interval))]
      }
```

**3rd:** **sapply** `findYearIndex` function to every element in year date `data.table`

```
> dt <- data.table(year = df)
> dt$YearIndex <- paste("YEAR", sapply(dt$year, findYearIndex), sep = "_")

> dt
  #         year       YearIndex
  #1: 2003-06-11          YEAR_1
  #2: 2004-08-11          YEAR_2
  #3: 2004-06-03          YEAR_2
  #4: 2004-01-20          YEAR_2
  #5: 2005-02-25          YEAR_3
  #6: 2003-01-07          YEAR_1
  #7: 2003-11-19          YEAR_2
  #8: 2003-03-12          YEAR_1
  #9: 2003-12-29          YEAR_2
 #10: 2003-03-26          YEAR_1
 #11: 2004-08-19          YEAR_2
 #12: 2004-07-19          YEAR_2
 #13: 2003-04-29          YEAR_1
 #14: 2003-05-06          YEAR_1
 #15: 2005-10-27 YEAR_integer(0)
 #ignore the rest of dt
```