# Matching time interval of one event with another event in R

Tags: r, intervals, lubridate, timespan

Am I trying to do the impossible? I want to match events in df1 with events in df2 if event2 or the period of 10 days before event2 intersects with a date in event1. I have pasted samples from the two datasets. I have looked and cannot find anything similar to this question on this forum, so maybe this is not possible. Thank you in advance!

```
head(df1)
    # A tibble: 6 x 1
    # Groups:   event1 [6]
      event1
       <date>     
    1 1980-01-10 
    2 1980-01-13 
    3 1980-01-14 
    4 1980-02-18 
    5 1980-02-27 
    6 1980-03-02 

head(df2)

      event2
    1  1980-01-16
    2  1980-01-18
    3  1980-01-19
    4  1980-02-12
    5  1980-09-26
    6  1980-10-23
```

I think what I want is something like this (using the first three event2s):

```
ev_1 <- interval(ymd('1980-01-06'), ymd('1980-01-16'))
ev_2 <- interval(ymd('1980-01-08'), ymd('1980-01-18')) 
ev_3 <- interval(ymd('1980-01-09'), ymd('1980-01-19'))
```

Then, I want to see if any of the event1 dates take place during an interval period. In total, I have about 60 event2 dates and hundreds of event1 dates over a 40 year period.

I was able to come up with this using instructions [here](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/within-interval.html), but is this the best approach? If so, is it possible to automate it so that I don't have to hand write all 60 intervals?

```
> dates_test <- ymd(c("1980-01-10", "1980-01-13", "1980-01-14", "1980-02-18"))
> interval_test<- list(interval(ymd('1980-01-06'), ymd('1980-01-16')),
                       interval(ymd('1980-01-09'), ymd('1980-01-19')))
> dates_test %within% interval_test
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Is the period you are describing an interval starting 10 days before event2 and ends at event2?

Comment: Yes. The dates for event1 are discrete days. For event2, I want the prior 10 day interval.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning "interval." Using that term as a search term led me to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497351/check-if-a-date-is-within-an-interval-in-r. I think there is an answer in there that fits for me. There are quite a few options, it seems!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create all possible combinations of event1 and event2 then keep rows when the event2 is 10 days or less after event1.

```
combinations <- expand.grid(df1$event1, df2$event2)
matches <- combinations[combinations[,2] >= combinations[,1] & combinations[,2] - combinations[,1] <= 10,]
matches

         Var1       Var2
1  1980-01-10 1980-01-16
2  1980-01-13 1980-01-16
3  1980-01-14 1980-01-16
7  1980-01-10 1980-01-18
8  1980-01-13 1980-01-18
9  1980-01-14 1980-01-18
13 1980-01-10 1980-01-19
14 1980-01-13 1980-01-19
15 1980-01-14 1980-01-19
```

Comment: Wow, that works perfectly! Thank you so much!!! Merci beaucoup!

Answer (score 1):

The OP has asked two questions:

1. Is using the `%within%` operator from `lubridate` the best approach?
2. Is it possible to automate it so that the OP does not have to hand write all 60 intervals?

To answer the second question first: Yes, it is possible:

#### `%within%`, `lapply()` and `interval()`

The OP was almost there. According to the [documentation](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/within-interval.html) of `a %within% b`,

> If `b` is a list of intervals, `a` is checked if it falls within *any* of
> the intervals

We can create a list of intervals from the given date vector `df2$event2` by

```
lapply(df2$event2, function(x) interval(x - 10, x))
```

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] 1980-01-06 UTC--1980-01-16 UTC
>
> [[2]]
> [1] 1980-01-08 UTC--1980-01-18 UTC
>
> [[3]]
> [1] 1980-01-09 UTC--1980-01-19 UTC
>
> [[4]]
> [1] 1980-02-02 UTC--1980-02-12 UTC
>
> [[5]]
> [1] 1980-09-16 UTC--1980-09-26 UTC
>
> [[6]]
> [1] 1980-10-13 UTC--1980-10-23 UTC
> ```

The `start` date of each interval is computed from the `end` date by subtracting 10 days. So,

```
library(lubridate)
df1$event1 %within% lapply(df2$event2, function(x) interval(x - 10, x))
```

returns a logical vector (in line with OP's expected result)

> ```
> [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> ```

which can be used to subset `df1` to pick the matching events from `df1` as a vector of dates

```
df1[df1$event1 %within% lapply(df2$event2, function(x) interval(x - 10, x)), ]
```

> ```
> [1] "1980-01-10" "1980-01-13" "1980-01-14"
> ```

or

```
df1[df1$event1 %within% lapply(df2$event2, function(x) interval(x - 10, x)), , drop = FALSE]
```

which returns the subsetted data.frame.

> ```
>       event1
> 1 1980-01-10
> 2 1980-01-13
> 3 1980-01-14
> ```

#### `%inrange%` from `data.table`

For the sake of completeness, the `data.table` package provides a similar operator `%inrange`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
df1[event1 %inrange% df2[, .(event2 - 10L, event2)]]
```

> ```
>        event1
> 1: 1980-01-10
> 2: 1980-01-13
> 3: 1980-01-14
> ```

`setDT(df1)` and `setDT(df2)` coerce data.frames to data.table objects.

#### Benchmarking

Now, we can try to answer OP's first question concerning *"the best approach"*.

The OP has not specified the criteria to judge an approach as "the best". Probably, the OP was mainly concerned about the effort to write 60 intervals by hand.

Now, this issue has ben solved so let's compare the three different approaches posted so far in terms of *execution speed*:

1. `%within%` and `interval()` from `lubridate`
2. `expand.grid()` suggested by [marcguery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63256798/3817004)
3. `%inrange%` from `data.table`

For benchmarking, the `bench` package is used because it measures exection times as well as memory allocation for varying problem sizes. It also checks that the results are identical. Therefore, the three approaches are modified to return a vector of dates.

```
library(bench)
library(ggplot2)
bm <- press(
  n1 = c(100L, 1E3L, 1E4L),
  n2 = c(10L, 100L, 1000L),
  {
    beg <- as.Date("1980-01-01")
    end <- as.Date("2020-12-31")
    df1 <- data.frame(event1 = seq(beg, end, length.out = n1))
    df2 <- data.frame(event2 = seq(beg, end, length.out = n2))
    dt1 <- as.data.table(df1)
    dt2 <- as.data.table(df2)
    mark(
      within = {
        df1[df1$event1 %within% lapply(df2$event2, function(x) interval(x - 10, x)), ]
      },
      inrange = {
        dt1[event1 %inrange% dt2[, .(event2 - 10L, event2)], event1]
      },
      exp.grid = {
        combinations <- expand.grid(df1$event1, df2$event2)
        matches <- combinations[combinations[,2] >= combinations[,1] & 
                       combinations[,2] - combinations[,1] <= 10,]
        unique(matches[[1L]])
      },
      check = TRUE
    )
  }
)
autoplot(bm)
```

[image]

Please, note the logarithmic time scale.

Only for the smallest problem sizes, the `expand.grid()` approach is the fastest. For all other problem sizes (including the case of 1000 `event1` and 100 `event2` which is close to OP's problem size), `data.table`'s `%inrange%` is the fastest. For the largest case with 10000 `event1` and 1000 `event2`, `data.table` is more than *2 magnitudes* faster than the other approaches.

```
library(dplyr)
bm %>% 
  select(1:11) %>% 
  filter(n1 == max(n1), n2 == max(n2)) %>% 
  mutate(expression = names(expression) %>% unique())
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 11
>   expression    n1    n2      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
>   <chr>      <int> <int> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
> 1 within     10000  1000 780.16ms  780.2ms      1.28     307MB     2.56     1     2      780ms
> 2 inrange    10000  1000   2.68ms    3.3ms    293.       491KB     0      147     0      502ms
> 3 exp.grid   10000  1000 834.35ms  834.3ms      1.20     882MB     3.60     1     3      834ms
> ```

Furthermore, `data.table` allocates *3 magnitudes* less memory (0.5MB vs 307MB or 882MB, resp.).