# Calculation of distribution using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

A quite straightforward question here.

I did do the search on all relevant posts on stackoverflow and google but failed to find the answer. Reference is made to [Find which interval row in a data frame that each element of a vector belongs in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41132081/find-which-interval-row-in-a-data-frame-that-each-element-of-a-vector-belongs-in/41136347) and [Split a vector into chunks in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318333/split-a-vector-into-chunks-in-r)

Data:

`Time Price Volume  Amount Flag
 1: 2016-01-04 09:05:06 105.0   9500  993700    1
 2: 2016-01-04 09:20:00 104.1  23500 2446350    0
 3: 2016-01-04 09:30:00 104.1  18500 1924550    1
 4: 2016-01-04 09:30:01 103.9  12500 1300550    0
 5: 2016-01-04 09:30:02 104.1  16118 1675233    1
 6: 2016-01-04 09:30:05 104.0  13000 1352200    0
 7: 2016-01-04 09:30:06 104.1   2500  260100    1
 8: 2016-01-04 09:30:07 104.1   1500  156150    1
 9: 2016-01-04 09:30:08 104.3    500   52150    1
10: 2016-01-04 09:30:10 104.0   1000  104000    0
11: 2016-01-04 09:30:11 103.9   1000  103900    0
12: 2016-01-04 09:30:15 104.0   3500  364450    1
13: 2016-01-04 09:30:17 104.3   2000  208450    1
14: 2016-01-04 09:30:19 104.3   1500  156450    1
15: 2016-01-04 09:30:20 104.4    500   52200    1
16: 2016-01-04 09:30:21 104.4   1500  156600    1
17: 2016-01-04 09:30:22 104.4   1000  104400    1
18: 2016-01-04 09:30:24 104.4   1500  156600    1
19: 2016-01-04 09:30:25 104.0   2000  208000    0
20: 2016-01-04 09:30:27 104.1   3500  364350    1`

Similar to preparation work for Histogram or `Hist` object, I would like to build distribution of `Volume` according to different levels of `Price`.

To be specific:

1. Divide the range of `Price` into N pieces/bins (Say, N = 5)
2. Sum up `Volume` for different bins

I tried `split` function, and several other such as `cut_number` function in `ggplot2` package. And I think `findInterval` might be helpful and the code should be like this:

```
library(data.table)
dt[, sum(Volume), by = findInterval(Price,cut_number(Price, 5))] # Do not work
# I think the key should be in `by` part. 
dt[, sum(Volume), by = some functions here]
```

Reproducible data

```
dt <- data.table(structure(list(Time
  = structure(c(1451898306, 1451899200,
  1451899800,1451899801, 1451899802,
  1451899805, 1451899806, 1451923195,
  1451923196,1451923200), class =
  c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone =
  "GMT"),Price = c(105, 104.1,
  104.1, 103.9, 104.1, 104, 104.1, 103,102.9, 102.9),
  Volume = c(9500L, 23500L, 18500L,
  12500L,16118L, 13000L, 2500L, 4000L, 2000L, 1000L),
  Amount = c(993700L,2446350L,
  1924550L, 1300550L, 1675233L, 1352200L, 260100L,412000L, 206016L, 102880L),
  Flag = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L,0L,
  1L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("Time",
  "Price", "Volume","Amount",
  "Flag"), class = c("data.table",
  "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,-10L)))
```

Desired Output (For illustration ONLY):

```
Price Range    Sum
102.3 - 102.5 300000
.
. (Total N bins, thus N rows)
.
105.0 - 105.3  500000
```

And also I tried several other combinations, all failed.

Any suggestions are welcome! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that N refers to number of pieces per bin and not number of rows. There is probably a shorter way without creating an index. But here is one where you group them first and then sum

```
setorder(dt, Price)
dt[,GROUP:=ceiling(seq_along(Price)/5)][, 
    list(PriceRange=paste(range(Price), collapse=" - "), 
         Volume=sum(Volume)), 
    by="GROUP"]
```

---

EDIT after OP's comments

If you want bands of equal width, you can use this:

```
dt[, sum(Volume), by=cut(Price, 5)]
```

If you want to show all bands, you can use this

```
dt[,Band:=cut(Price, 5)]
dt[dt[, list(Band=levels(Band))], on="Band"][, sum(Volume, na.rm=TRUE), by="Band"]
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks @chinsoon12, In your post, N stands for the numbers (i.e sample size) per bin. Actually in the context of my programming, N stands for the number of bins. No need to divide the total population into bins equally. Could you provide some ideas for that case. Thanks a lot!