# Efficiently Binning Data into specified bins with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two dataframes - a dataframe of 7 bins, specifying the limits and name of each bin (called FJX_bins) and a frame of wavelength-sigma pairs (test_spectra). I want to create a new variable in Test_Spectra entitled bin_number based on the bin limits in the `FJX_bins` data. The `dput` of the two is included below.

It would be relatively easy to brute force this with `mutate` and `case_when`, but the key here is that I would like the solution to be extensible to an arbitrary number of bins. My feeling is that there is likely to be some sort of `apply` method in `dplyr` that could be of use here, but all I could think to do was use a for loop, as shown here:

```
df <- test_spectra %>%
  mutate(bin_number = case_when(
    for(ii in 1:nrow(FJX_bins)){
      Wavelength >= FJX_bins$Lambda_Start[ii] & Wavelength < FJX_bins$Lambda_End[ii] ~
        FJX_bins$Bin_Number[ii]}
    ))
```

This strategy fails, and throws the error

> Case 1 (`for (ii in 1:nrow(FJX_bins)) {...`) must be a two-sided formula, not a NULL

Is there a way to use `dplyr` to solve this question? Or do I need to step back and look at something like `apply` and `cut`? I'd rather stick within a `dplyr` framework for other reasons, but could go outside of it, too.

Thanks

```
FJX_bins <- structure(list(Bin_Number = 1:7, Lambda_Start = c(289, 298.25, 
307.45, 312.45, 320.3, 345, 412.45), Lambda_End = c(298.25, 307.45, 
312.45, 320.3, 345, 412.45, 850)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(
    Bin_Number = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), Lambda_Start = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Lambda_End = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Effective_Lambda = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("Bin_Number", "Lambda_Start", 
"Lambda_End", "Effective_Lambda")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"), .Names = c("Bin_Number", 
"Lambda_Start", "Lambda_End"))

test_spectra <- structure(list(Wavelength = c(289L, 290L, 291L, 292L, 293L, 294L, 
295L, 296L, 297L, 298L, 299L, 300L, 289L, 290L, 291L, 292L, 293L, 
294L, 295L, 296L, 297L, 298L, 299L, 300L, 289L, 290L, 291L, 292L, 
293L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 297L, 298L, 299L, 300L, 289L, 290L, 291L, 
292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 297L, 298L, 299L, 300L), Sigma = c(3.97790085259898e-20, 
3.88773011066234e-20, 3.77170497723194e-20, 3.63990173255768e-20, 
3.53611020195826e-20, 3.39379425027765e-20, 3.24540998352932e-20, 
3.08629426249589e-20, 2.93243925380076e-20, 2.80431593390348e-20, 
2.64345023340469e-20, 2.49597804268261e-20, 4.79587956800083e-20, 
4.67040607723134e-20, 4.5134283789068e-20, 4.32731814710643e-20, 
4.13196812361237e-20, 3.93856298421813e-20, 3.77050786831795e-20, 
3.62340670271797e-20, 3.49404344374885e-20, 3.36066462681245e-20, 
3.20871974271263e-20, 3.03438697547602e-20, 5.27803299371575e-20, 
5.12475486084599e-20, 4.99112054163632e-20, 4.86399784101602e-20, 
4.73236079731255e-20, 4.56798834656559e-20, 4.36887241590191e-20, 
4.13697643104457e-20, 3.89697643104457e-20, 3.66909671059429e-20, 
3.46634646072095e-20, 3.28648835305714e-20, 5.71590756444018e-20, 
5.57618648066173e-20, 5.44949261656802e-20, 5.33110977304272e-20, 
5.21177991137917e-20, 5.07478142704849e-20, 4.9100984463428e-20, 
4.70660943398542e-20, 4.47661068638463e-20, 4.24314737804269e-20, 
4.02176301884806e-20, 3.82570654305878e-20)), row.names = c(NA, 
-48L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("Wavelength", 
"Sigma"))
```

Comment: Looks very similar to this sort of thing - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41132081/find-which-interval-row-in-a-data-frame-that-each-element-of-a-vector-belongs-in/41133991

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fuzzyjoin` implements `dplyr` range/interval joins:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

interval_left_join(
    FJX_bins, 
    test_spectra,
    by = c('Wavelength' = 'Lambda_Start', 'Wavelength' = 'Lambda_End')
)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 52 x 5
>    Wavelength    Sigma Bin_Number Lambda_Start Lambda_End
>         <int>    <dbl>      <int>        <dbl>      <dbl>
>  1        289 3.98e-20          1          289       298.
>  2        290 3.89e-20          1          289       298.
>  3        291 3.77e-20          1          289       298.
>  4        292 3.64e-20          1          289       298.
>  5        293 3.54e-20          1          289       298.
>  6        294 3.39e-20          1          289       298.
>  7        295 3.25e-20          1          289       298.
>  8        296 3.09e-20          1          289       298.
>  9        297 2.93e-20          1          289       298.
> 10        298 2.80e-20          1          289       298.
> # … with 42 more rows
> ```

Comment: This works perfectly and is exactly what I was hoping to find. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

with dplyr:

To create bin number as a factor

```
library(dplyr)
Test_Spectra <- mutate(test_spectra, 
                       bin = cut(Wavelength, breaks = c(FJX_bins$Lambda_Start, 850), 
                                 labels = FJX_bins$Bin_Number, right = F))
```

Or to create bin number as a character variable

```
Test_Spectra <- mutate(test_spectra, 
                       bin = as.character(cut(Wavelength, 
                                          breaks = c(FJX_bins$Lambda_Start, 850), 
                                          labels = FJX_bins$Bin_Number, right = F)))
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you don't find a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test_spectra)
setDT(FJX_bins)
test_spectra[FJX_bins, 
             bin_number := i.Bin_Number, 
             on = .(Wavelength >= Lambda_Start, Wavelength < Lambda_End)]
```

This makes a non-equi join with the bins table and sets the bin number accordingly.