# Conditionally join R tables based on nested membership

Tags: r, join, dplyr, data.table

Consider this example nested dataframe of 3 counties, 3 towns, and a range of zip codes associated with them. Two of the towns share the same name (`B`), but are in different counties:

```
df <- tibble(
  county = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3),
  town = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B"),
  zip = c(12864,12865,12866,89501,89502,89503,89504,76512)) %>% 
  nest(data=c(zip))
```

I have another dataframe that contains town names, a zipcode, and a placeholder value, but is missing the county field:

```
df2 <- tibble(
  town = c("A", "B", "B"),
  zip = c(12866, 89504, 76512),
  value = c("foo", "bar", "ski"))
```

My real data has hundreds of instances of these duplicated town names, and I need to join these two tables together so that each town gets the correct placeholder value based on the zip code (not the town name, which has duplicates). However, `dplyr` only seems [to join on equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52648580/how-to-do-a-conditional-join-in-r-with-dplyr). As such, I'm stuck - what I'm after is something like `inner_join(df, df2, by = c(df2$zip %in% df$data$zip))`, but that obviously doesn't work.

I'm also aware of `data.table` being able to [handle inequality in joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42684429/r-conditional-join-based-on-timestamp-interval), but this always seems to relate to greater than/less than conditionals. How can I successfully join these tables to return the following output, in situations where I have more than 3 neatly matched rows between the dataframes?

```
  county town  data             value
   <dbl> <chr> <list>           <chr>
1      1 A     <tibble [3 x 1]> foo  
2      2 B     <tibble [4 x 1]> bar  
3      3 B     <tibble [1 x 1]> ski
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do this with `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(value = map_chr(data, ~ inner_join(.x, df2, by = 'zip') %>% 
          pull(value)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  county town  data             value
   <dbl> <chr> <list>           <chr>
1      1 A     <tibble [3 × 1]> foo  
2      2 B     <tibble [4 × 1]> bar  
3      3 B     <tibble [1 × 1]> ski
```

---

Or another option is `regex_inner_join`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
    mutate(zip = map_chr(data, ~ str_c(.x$zip, collapse="|"))) %>% 
    regex_inner_join(df2 %>%
          select(-town), by = "zip") %>% 
    select(-starts_with('zip'))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  county town  data             value
   <dbl> <chr> <list>           <chr>
1      1 A     <tibble [3 × 1]> foo  
2      2 B     <tibble [4 × 1]> bar  
3      3 B     <tibble [1 × 1]> ski
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to "roll your own join":

```
df %>% mutate(value = df2$value[
  sapply(data, function(x) match(unlist(x), df2$zip) %>% .[!is.na(.)])
  ])
```

This works for the example provided, but I'm not clear whether there could be multiple matches to df2$zip within a group of df$data$zip's.