# R dplyr left_join error - missing values produced when joining values rounded to one decimal place

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join

UPDATE:  Following comments (thanks!) I have now successfully merge these datasets by converting the ratios from 'double' to 'character'.  I am still interested to know why R has trouble merging rounded 'double' variables though (the problem occurs also when using `merge` and `sqldf` and is not restricted to dplyr).

I have been having trouble with merging dataframes using dplyr’s left_join and ‘double’ variables..  I’m attempting to join small tables of data (only 20 rows) on the basis of a grouping of the ratio of target to predictor to identify what proportion of these ratios fall within 5% bandings for training, validation and test set results (from models produced by h2o).

To produce the groups of ratio I’ve simply rounded them to the nearest one decimal place (so the ratio variable remains a ‘double’ type like the original calculated value).  However, when I attempt to merge on these rounded values, random rows of NAs appear in the merged dataframe.

Here’s an example of the code and the tables produced - the final table has a row of missing values for the ratios rounded to 0.7, but all are present in the original tables.

Is this a possible bug?

(I know that I could do the calculations more efficiently in dplyr, but as it’s not merging at the moment there seems little point in tidying things up).

```
trainR <- mutate(trainR, ratio_GBM = round((ZZ_TOP_PRICE_R/pred_GBM),digits=1))
> train_pcs_GBM <- count(trainR, ratio_GBM)
> train_pcs_GBM <- rename(train_pcs_GBM, train_count_GBM = n)
> train_pcs_GBM <- mutate(train_pcs_GBM, train_pc_GBM = round((train_count_GBM/length(trainR$ratio_GBM)*100),1))
> train_pcs_GBM
# A tibble: 32 x 3
   ratio_GBM train_count_GBM train_pc_GBM
       <dbl>           <int>        <dbl>
 1       0.0               1          0.0
 2       0.1              15          0.0
 3       0.2             302          0.1
 4       0.3             440          0.1
 5       0.4            1575          0.3
 6       0.5           23304          4.6
 7       0.6           62381         12.4
 8       0.7           71098         14.1
 9       0.8           65792         13.0
10       0.9           66991         13.3
# ... with 22 more rows
> #View(train_pcs_GBM)
> 
> validR <- mutate(validR, ratio_GBM = round((ZZ_TOP_PRICE_R/pred_GBM),digits=1))
> valid_pcs_GBM <- count(validR, ratio_GBM)
> valid_pcs_GBM <- rename(valid_pcs_GBM, valid_count_GBM = n)
> valid_pcs_GBM <- mutate(valid_pcs_GBM, valid_pc_GBM = round((valid_count_GBM/length(validR$ratio_GBM)*100),1))
> valid_pcs_GBM
# A tibble: 34 x 3
   ratio_GBM valid_count_GBM valid_pc_GBM
       <dbl>           <int>        <dbl>
 1       0.1               9          0.0
 2       0.2             148          0.1
 3       0.3             168          0.1
 4       0.4             688          0.4
 5       0.5            8058          4.8
 6       0.6           20980         12.5
 7       0.7           23446         14.0
 8       0.8           21932         13.1
 9       0.9           22030         13.1
10       1.0           19342         11.5
# ... with 24 more rows
> View(valid_pcs_GBM)
> 
> testR <- mutate(testR, ratio_GBM = round((ZZ_TOP_PRICE_R/pred_GBM),digits=1))
> test_pcs_GBM <- count(testR, ratio_GBM)
> test_pcs_GBM <- rename(test_pcs_GBM, test_count_GBM = n)
> test_pcs_GBM <- mutate(test_pcs_GBM, test_pc_GBM = round((test_count_GBM/length(testR$ratio_GBM)*100),1))
> test_pcs_GBM
# A tibble: 31 x 3
   ratio_GBM test_count_GBM test_pc_GBM
       <dbl>          <int>       <dbl>
 1       0.1             10         0.0
 2       0.2            148         0.1
 3       0.3            154         0.1
 4       0.4            600         0.4
 5       0.5           8359         5.0
 6       0.6          20739        12.4
 7       0.7          23283        13.9
 8       0.8          21899        13.1
 9       0.9          22216        13.2
10       1.0          19202        11.4
# ... with 21 more rows
> 
> # Merge table of percentages ******************************************************************************
> res_GBM <- data.frame(ratio = numeric(20))
> res_GBM$ratio <- seq(0.1,2,0.1)
> res_GBM <- left_join(res_GBM, train_pcs_GBM, by = c("ratio" = "ratio_GBM"))
> res_GBM <- left_join(res_GBM, valid_pcs_GBM, by = c("ratio" = "ratio_GBM"))
> res_GBM <- left_join(res_GBM, test_pcs_GBM, by = c("ratio" = "ratio_GBM"))
> res_GBM
   ratio train_count_GBM train_pc_GBM valid_count_GBM valid_pc_GBM test_count_GBM test_pc_GBM
1    0.1              15          0.0               9          0.0             10         0.0
2    0.2             302          0.1             148          0.1            148         0.1
3    0.3              NA           NA              NA           NA             NA          NA
4    0.4            1575          0.3             688          0.4            600         0.4
5    0.5           23304          4.6            8058          4.8           8359         5.0
6    0.6           62381         12.4           20980         12.5          20739        12.4
7    0.7              NA           NA              NA           NA             NA          NA
8    0.8           65792         13.0           21932         13.1          21899        13.1
9    0.9           66991         13.3           22030         13.1          22216        13.2
10   1.0           58921         11.7           19342         11.5          19202        11.4
11   1.1           47096          9.3           15071          9.0          15086         9.0
12   1.2              NA           NA              NA           NA             NA          NA
13   1.3              NA           NA              NA           NA             NA          NA
14   1.4              NA           NA              NA           NA             NA          NA
15   1.5              NA           NA              NA           NA             NA          NA
16   1.6            6761          1.3            2372          1.4           2359         1.4
17   1.7              NA           NA              NA           NA             NA          NA
18   1.8              NA           NA              NA           NA             NA          NA
19   1.9              NA           NA              NA           NA             NA          NA
20   2.0            1095          0.2             482          0.3            435         0.3
> 
with(DL_FC_res, lineplot(ratio, test_pc, train_pc, valid_pc, FC_pc))
```

Comment: Can you `dput` your data so that we can reproduce the error?

Comment: I think, it's possible, because you can't compare double values with `==`. Try to convert them to strings. Probably related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37289405/704329

Comment: @Lyngbahr - I don't know how to do that I'm afraid at the moment.  Extracts of the to-be-merged tables are there in the console output I copied.

Comment: @wl2776 - I'll try that, but it is clearly managing to match some cases, but not others.

Comment: I have also now tried using the 'sqldf' package and am getting the same problem.

Comment: Thank you everyone.  I have managed to successfully merge the tables by converting the rounded ratio values to characters using as.character(ratio)

Comment: @AdrianD Values of the class `double` are floating point numbers, which don't represent decimal fractions exaclty. Sometimes exact matches occur because two vectors created through different floating point operations turn out to be the same, but that's a happy coincidence. See [this](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) answer from R FAQ for example.