# Find all rows from one dataframe based on date looked into the date range in other dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames as mentioned below:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,2,3,4,4), actual.date=c('10/01/1996','10/02/1996','5/01/2002','7/01/1999','9/01/2005','5/01/2006','2/03/2003'),
val=c(5,10,15,20,25,30,35))
dcis <- grep('date$',names(df1))
df1[dcis] <- lapply(df1[dcis],as.Date,'%m/%d/%Y')
df1

df2 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4), before.date=c('10/1/1996','1/1/1998','1/1/2000','1/1/2001','1/1/2001','1/1/2001','10/1/2004','10/3/2004'), after.date=c('12/1/1996','9/30/2003','12/31/2004','3/31/2006','9/30/2006','9/30/2005','12/30/2004','11/28/2004'))
dcis <- grep('date$',names(df2))
df2[dcis] <- lapply(df2[dcis],as.Date,'%m/%d/%Y')
df2
```

Requirement -> I will start with each row of `df2` and see how many rows in `df1` lies within (inclusive range) date range specified in that row of `df2` (grouped on ID).

For ex: for 1st row in `df2`, there are 2 rows in `df1` (1st and 2nd) which has ID=1 and lies in date range of 1st row of `df2`. In the final output, I will sum 5+10 (from column 'val') and put against 1st row of `df2`.

Comment: This fake data doesn't seem to work, could you use dput

Answer (score 1):

We can use a non-equi join in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
val1 <- setDT(df1)[df2, sum(val), on = .(ID, actual.date >= before.date, 
           actual.date <= after.date), by = .EACHI]$V1
df2$val <- val1
df2$val
#[1] 15 15 15 NA 25 35 NA NA
```

---

Or another option is a `fuzzy_join`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
fuzzy_right_join(df1, df2, by = c("ID",
    "actual.date" = "before.date", "actual.date"= "after.date"), 
      match_fun = list(`==`, `>=`, `<=`)) %>%
 group_by(ID = ID.y, before.date, after.date) %>% 
 summarise(val = sum(val, na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   ID, before.date [8]
#     ID before.date after.date   val
#  <dbl> <date>      <date>     <dbl>
#1     1 1996-10-01  1996-12-01    15
#2     1 1998-01-01  2003-09-30    15
#3     1 2000-01-01  2004-12-31    15
#4     2 2001-01-01  2006-03-31     0
#5     3 2001-01-01  2006-09-30    25
#6     4 2001-01-01  2005-09-30    35
#7     4 2004-10-01  2004-12-30     0
#8     4 2004-10-03  2004-11-28     0
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what your are after. Here is a base R solution

```
df2$res <- apply(df2,1, function(x) sum(df1$val[df1$ID == x["ID"] 
                                                & df1$actual.date>= x["before.date"] 
                                                & df1$actual.date<= x["after.date"]]))
```

such that

```
> df2
  ID before.date after.date res
1  1  1996-10-01 1996-12-01  15
2  1  1998-01-01 2003-09-30  15
3  1  2000-01-01 2004-12-31  15
4  2  2001-01-01 2006-03-31   0
5  3  2001-01-01 2006-09-30  25
6  4  2001-01-01 2005-09-30  35
7  4  2004-10-01 2004-12-30   0
8  4  2004-10-03 2004-11-28   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this a duplicate post

[dplyr left_join by less than, greater than condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289405/dplyr-left-join-by-less-than-greater-than-condition)

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(dummy=TRUE) %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% mutate(dummy=TRUE)) %>%
  filter(actual.date >= before.date, actual.date < after.date) %>%
  select(-dummy)
```

We also have fuzzyjoin.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

fuzzy_inner_join(df1,df2,
                  by = c("actual.date" = "before.date","actual.date" = "after.date","ID" = "ID"),
                  match_fun = list(`>=`, `<=`,`==`))
```