# Joining events and compute the time difference only AFTER the specific datetime of a condition is met

Tags: r, datetime, group-by, data-wrangling

I am trying to figure out a way to code in R how to join two dataframes  to obtain the following:

1. The time diference between the  ***FIRST bad report**  and **the first call** a teacher takes to call each student´s parent ***AFTER*** that first bad report is recorded
2. make a count of the numbers of calls a teacher has called the parents of a student **AFTER the FIRST bad report** for each student.

To Ilustrate here are the tables:

| DATE_REPORT | STUDENT_ID | REPORT_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-23 10:53:34.565 | H-007 | UDJ-83 |
| 2021-02-25 17:02:29.99 | H-007 | UDJ-84 |
| 2021-02-28 17:02:29.100 | H-008 | UDJ-85 |

```
BAD_REPORTS<-data.frame(
  "DATE_REPORT"=c("2021-02-23 10:53:34.565",
                  "2021-02-25 17:02:29.99",
                  "2021-02-28 17:02:29.100"),
  "STUDENT_ID"=c("H-007",
                 "H-007",
                 "H-008"),
  "REPORT_CODE"=c("UDJ-83",
  "UDJ-84","UDJ-85"))
```

This table shows the dates of the bad report for FEB by STUDENT_ID

the following table shows the records of the calls the teacher has made the same month

| DATE_CAL | STUDENT_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-10 12:21:07 | H-007 |
| 2021-02-23 10:26:08 | H-007 |
| 2021-02-26 11:09:36 | H-007 |
| 2021-02-26 11:16:46 | H-007 |
| 2021-02-27 11:16:46 | H-008 |

```
CALLS_BY_TEACHER<-data.frame(
  "DATE_CAL"=c("2021-02-10 12:21:07",
            "2021-02-23 10:26:08",
            "2021-02-26 11:09:36",
            "2021-02-26 11:16:46",
            "2021-02-27 11:16:46"),
"STUDENT_ID"=c("H-007",
             "H-007",
             "H-007",
             "H-007",
             "H-008"))
```

Im looking for a table like this:

| STUDENT_ID | DATE_FIRST_REPORT | FIRST_CALL_AFTER_FIRST_REPORT | DIF_TIME | REPORT_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H-007 | 2021-02-23 10:53:34.565 | 2021-02-26 11:09:36 | 4336.024 | UDJ-83 |
| H-007 | 2021-02-28 17:02:29.100 | NA | NA | UDJ-85 |

This would be correct because AFTER the first report of this month the teacher called student H-007 on 2021-02-26 11:09:36      (4336.024  mins after the first bad report)

what am I doing?

I have tried to do a full join and then group by STUDENT_ID and REPORT and I select the min(DATE_REPORT) because I know that it has to be the very first date of report but I am kind of lost when I have to code that the first date of call to be taken into consideration will have to be the one RIGHT AFTER the date of the first bad report for each student... so if someone could link some documentation that would be great THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP

sidenote: If there is no call on the teacher's behalf after a student's frist report than the diff time would be NA

Comment: A time difference of 180,26 min is longer than 12 days, which seems incorrect.

Comment: Yeah! I have corrected the example thank you for pointing that out. I am new to R @mt1022 thank you for helping me out do you know I way to do this using the library tidyverse?

Comment: Non-equi join is a special feature of `data.table`. For tidyverse, a possible way is to join by student_id and then filter manually. See here for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289405/dplyr-left-join-by-less-than-greater-than-condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(BAD_REPORTS)
setDT(CALLS_BY_TEACHER)

BAD_REPORTS[, c('idate', 'itime') := IDateTime(DATE_REPORT)]
CALLS_BY_TEACHER[, c('idate', 'itime') := IDateTime(DATE_CAL)]

CALLS_BY_TEACHER[BAD_REPORTS[!duplicated(STUDENT_ID)],
    on = .(STUDENT_ID, idate >= idate, itime > itime), mult = 'first'][, .(
        STUDENT_ID,
        DATE_FIRST_REPORT = DATE_REPORT,
        FIRST_CALL_AFTER_FIRST_REPORT = DATE_CAL,
        DIFF_TIME = difftime(DATE_CAL, DATE_REPORT, units='mins'),
        REPORT_CODE)]

#    STUDENT_ID       DATE_FIRST_REPORT FIRST_CALL_AFTER_FIRST_REPORT     DIFF_TIME REPORT_CODE
# 1:      H-007 2021-02-23 10:53:34.565           2021-02-26 11:09:36 4336.024 mins      UDJ-83
# 2:      H-008 2021-02-28 17:02:29.100                          <NA>       NA mins      UDJ-85
```

Comment: your code works 10/10 for my problem thank you for showing me a new way of doing things, the link you provided with about dyplr helped me to create a new solution, basically I do a left join to then select call dates that are greater than the report days, and after that I just pick the last call with the last report by group of IDS, just pointing that out if anyone is interested in an alternative solution, THANK YOU so much @mt1022 it  was your help, time and effort that allow me to solve this problem and learn!!!! thanks a milllion! you dont know how happy I am thank so much my friend